# is this object empty, Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax system set up.  When the MySQL query returns no data, I need it to pass an empty object back.  I create a node called 'data' in the php script and even when the query returns no data I pass $data['success'] = 1.

The trick is I can't figure out how to check to see if the query was returned data or not.

I have tried...

```
// sub responseObj.data for responseObj.data[0] for the following if's
if(responseObj.data[0].length == -1)  

if(responseObj.data[0] == null)

if(responseObj == undefined)
//edit: added this...
if(!responseObj.data[0])
```

and I've really lost tack of any other various snippet's i've tried.

**EDIT: adding xml generated that is passed to my script**
XML - returning zero results

```
<response_myCallbackFunction>  
  <success>1</success>  
<response_myCallbackFunction>
```

XML - returning a populated query

```
<response_myCallbackFunction>  
  <data> 
  <random_data>this is data</random_data>  
  </data>  
  <success>1</success>  
<response_myCallbackFunction>
```

---

**Is there a way to check to see if an object is empty in javascript?**

-thanks

Comment: can you add a snippet from your php for what you are returning

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test for an empty Javascript object from JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Obj.hasOwnProperty('blah')` does not seem to work for checking to see if the property exists.

```
function isEmptyObj(obj){
  for(var i in obj){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

isEmptyObj({a:1}); //returns true

isEmptyObj({}); //returns false
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
if( responseObj["data"] ) {
   // do stuff with data
}
```

or

```
if( responseObj.hasOwnProperty("data") && responseObj.data ) {
   // do stuff with data
}
```

Comment: nope... I thought responseObj.hasOwnProperty("data") would have done it... but no go... grr

Comment: ahh... I just read Obj.hasOwnProperty('property') cannot check for the existence of a property. ( http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/g/shasownproperty.htm )

Comment: not sure where you are looking... hasOwnProperty() can check for existence of a property (hence the name). Would suggest NOT reading about javascript on about.com :D

Comment: sure, Mozilla Developer Center has some great docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Object:hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof responseObj.data != 'undefined') {
   // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for ES5 you have `getOwnPropertyNames` :

```
var o = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).length // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If `responseObj` is the XML Document object (from the `xhr.responseXML` property), then:

```
if (responseObj.getElementsByTagName("data").length > 0) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

If `responseObj` is a JavaScript object:

```
if (responseObj.data) {
    // do stuff...
}
```