# Javascript trivia: check for equality against the empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json).**

Silly javascript question: I want to check if an object is the emtpy object.

I call *empty object* the object that results from using the empty object literal, as in:

```
 var o = {};
```

As expected, neither `==` nor `===` work, as the two following statements

```
 alert({}=={});
 alert({}==={});
```

give false.

Examples of expressions that **do not** evaluate to the empty object:

- `0`
- `""`
- `{a:"b"}`
- `[]`
- `new function(){}`

So what is the shortest way to evaluate for the empty object?

Comment: An interesting question. A quick tap in the search engine of my choice has shown that its not actually that easy! This thread might help a little tho : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
function isEmpty(o){
    for(var i in o){
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to test if an object is "empty":

```
if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
  // "empty" object
} else {
  // not empty
}
```

Comment: that's the right answer. For who needs to have this working on IE8 check the es5-shim library.

Comment: This is 10 times slower than the (for...in) option - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax

```
if (a.toSource() === "({})")
```

but this doesn't work in IE. As an alternative to the "toSource()" method encode to JSON of the ajax libraries can be used:

For example,

```
var o = {};
alert($.toJSON(o)=='{}'); // true

var o = {a:1};
alert($.toJSON(o)=='{}'); // false
```

jquery + jquery.json

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a short way to determine if an object is empty has Javascript creates an object and internally adds `constructor` and `prototype` properties of Object automatically.

You can create your own `isEmpty()` method like this:

```
var obj={}
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
    }
    return true;
};
alert(obj.isEmpty());
```

So, if any object has any property, then the object is not empty else return true.

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:
     cs = 'MTobj={   }; JSON.stringify(MTobj)=="{}"';
     alert(cs+'  is  '+eval(cs));
     cs = 'MTnot={a:2}; JSON.stringify(MTnot)=="{}"';
     alert(cs+'  is  '+eval(cs));
```

says

```
MTobj={   }; JSON.stringify(MTobj)=="{}"  is  true
MTnot={a:2}; JSON.stringify(MTnot)=="{}"  is  false
```

---

Caveat! Beware! there can be false positives!

```
javascript:
     cs = 'MTobj={ f:function(){} }; JSON.stringify(MTobj)=="{}"';
     alert(cs+'  is  '+eval(cs));
     alert("The answer is wrong!!\n\n"+
                    (cs="JSON.stringify({ f:function(){} })")+
                             "\n\n  returns\n\n"+eval(cs));
```

Comment: This is extremely unsafe and slow for no good reason to be unsafe and slow.