# Is object empty?

Tags: javascript

What is the fastest way to check if an object is empty or not?

Is there a faster and better way than this:

```
function count_obj(obj){
    var i = 0;
    for(var key in obj){
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to count the properties (this is what the code is doing) or just test whether the object is empty or not (this is stated in your question)?

Comment: Just as a recommendation of libraries that are capable of this [is.js](http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: For utilities like this, it is recommended to use some libraries out there. You could use lodash and use something like `_.isEmpty(_.keys(yourObject))`. And I believe you can now import those two methods individually, and not the whole lodash library.

Comment: [Direct speed comparison here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787784/4575793)

Answer (score 463, accepted):

I'm assuming that by *empty* you mean "has no properties of its own".

```
// Speed up calls to hasOwnProperty
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

function isEmpty(obj) {

    // null and undefined are "empty"
    if (obj == null) return true;

    // Assume if it has a length property with a non-zero value
    // that that property is correct.
    if (obj.length > 0)    return false;
    if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

    // If it isn't an object at this point
    // it is empty, but it can't be anything *but* empty
    // Is it empty?  Depends on your application.
    if (typeof obj !== "object") return true;

    // Otherwise, does it have any properties of its own?
    // Note that this doesn't handle
    // toString and valueOf enumeration bugs in IE < 9
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Examples:

```
isEmpty(""), // true
isEmpty(33), // true (arguably could be a TypeError)
isEmpty([]), // true
isEmpty({}), // true
isEmpty({length: 0, custom_property: []}), // true

isEmpty("Hello"), // false
isEmpty([1,2,3]), // false
isEmpty({test: 1}), // false
isEmpty({length: 3, custom_property: [1,2,3]}) // false
```

If you only need to handle [ECMAScript5 browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=use-strict), you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) instead of the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/hasOwnProperty) loop:

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length > 0) return false;
```

This will ensure that even if the object only has non-enumerable properties `isEmpty` will still give you the correct results.

Comment: JSLint is complaining `hasOwnProperty is a really bad name`. This fixes it `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`. Credits [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/275)

Comment: @frequent - `var hasOwnProp` would probably also work :-)  We're looking to avoid as many lookups as possible (in case this is called in a place where performance kind of matters [if it really matters only profiling will tell you the fastest way on each platform]).

Comment: @SeanVieira: hm. I will try. Sort of had an argument with JSLint regarding having props ;-)

Comment: Just curious..shouldn't we check if it is actually an object?

Comment: Mhh, you cannot read the property `length` of `null` and `undefined`...

Comment: @SeanVieira Does the javascript object have any `length` associated with it, I mean in its `prototype`?? It is always `undefined`. And can you run the `for loop` to check for `var obj = {a : 1};` The loop should return true not false.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary - A custom JS object might *provide* a `length` property.  As to `for (key in someobj) { return true; }`, `for ... in` iterates over properties on the prototype as well, so the object itself may be empty, but it may have inherited properties.

Comment: @SeanVieira I understand that but you are iterating the loop on the object not on it's prototype. Can you have a look at [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/chneha89/ztHz2/).

Comment: @NehaChoudhary - if you look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VKkzQ/1/) you'll see the kind of situation this is designed to avoid.

Comment: I want to point out that this is much faster than the methods offered by ECMAScript5: http://jsperf.com/empty-object-comparisons.

Comment: Just a minor enhancement. The line: `if (obj.length && obj.length > 0)    return false;` shouldn't be simply `if (obj.length > 0) return false;` ?

Comment: In **livescript**:

`has-own-property = Object.prototype.has-own-property

is-empty-object = (o) ->
    unless o? then true
    if o.length > 0 then false
    if o.length is 0 then true

    for key of o
        if has-own-property.call o, key then return false

    return true`

Comment: I have done some performance tests below  - the (for...in) option presented here is a better choice than the Object.keys() one presented in some of the other proposals.  :)

Comment: for a number this would return true, not false as it should. The last line should be replaced with return isNum(obj).

Comment: @ganjan - it *is* empty (as in it cannot have any properties).  That may not be correct (depending on what you're doing passing a primitive could actually be an unrecoverable error).  That said, I updated the code to note that we are treating primitives as empty and noting that this may be something you want to change.  (And nice catch!)

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty/4994265#4994265) is probably much better / simpler as of current day, no?

Answer (score 647):

For ECMAScript5 (not supported in all browsers yet though), you can use:

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0
```

Comment: A more proper ES5 solution would be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length == 0` because `Object.keys` only gets the *enumerable* properties. In ES5 we have the power of defining property attributes, we could have an object with non-enumerable properties and `Object.keys` will just return an empty array... `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` returns an array containing *all* the own properties of an object, even if they aren't enumerable.

Comment: @CMS `getOwnPropertyNames` is [recommended against by Crockford](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTEqr0IlFKY#t=30m43s). According to him, this method was introduced to the language specifically for Caja (and other secure frameworks, I guess). So, there is a chance that this method is not or will not be available in certain environments.

Comment: This is the ECMAScript5 compatibility table: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Comment: This answer now [works in all modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/); definitely the best one unless you need to support IE8-.

Comment: This is 10 times slower for empty objects than using the (for... in) option - see performance tests above.

Comment: It's quite unbelievable that Object.isEmpty() isn't part of javascript yet

Comment: @CMS, unfortunately, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames([])` returns `["length"]`, so it'd not work for arrays...

Comment: Semantically, I think, an object with zero enumerable properties **should** be considered "empty" (because unenumerable declared properties were probably meant to be "private"), so `Object.keys.length` is probably the right way to go.

Comment: For Vue.js users, `getOwnPropertyNames` will include framework change-detection observers that probably you don't need.  So `Object.keys` is what you want.

Answer (score 226):

**EDIT**: Note that you should probably use [ES5 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994265/593487) instead of this since ES5 support is [widespread](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5) these days. It still works for jQuery though.

---

Easy and cross-browser way is by using `jQuery.isEmptyObject`:

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(obj))
{
    // do something
}
```

More: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/

You need jquery though.

Comment: I'm amused that the jQuery option is the one that is "exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty", over [a native ES5 solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994265/425313).  This answer is still useful in some cases, I suppose.

Comment: ES5 solution is not supported in all browsers (yet - at least AFAIK), so this solution makes sense if you are already using jQuery (which many sites are). Also, jQuery is a bit more efficient than Jakob's solution (not that it matters much in most cases though), as it doesn't traverse whole object before calculating the length - it returns [false as soon as a key is found](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L241).

Comment: This doesn't work in IE8. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: I doubt that's still true, if it ever was (the code is pretty standard) - but if you have an example and can validate on IE8, you should file a bug report with jQuery. They are pretty serious about that.

Comment: It's not cross browser since browsers do not include jQuery.

Comment: @Pier I feel like you're being intentionally obtuse here. Cross-browser doesn't indicate that it's included in the browser itself, merely that it works universally across the major accepted browsers.

Answer (score 101):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty) each have a convenient `isEmpty()` function, if you don't mind adding an extra library.

```
_.isEmpty({});
```

Comment: Or for people who have already included underscore ;)

Comment: Late comment: as for 2016 you can use just lodash _isEmpty_ (you don't need to import all the lodash, you can now import just a method from it, it was divided to multiple micro-packages in npm).

Comment: Yeah or you could import `node_modules/*` and ignore any dependency you take on any plugin </sarcasm>

Comment: The roll-your-own solutions are great for learning the intricacies of the language, but for production use it's best to leverage a robust library such as lodash.  Lodash has been stress tested for both performance and corner cases.  _.isEmpty() is convenient because it supports objects, arrays, just about anything.

Comment: You can also inspect the source and see if you need to import this: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.14/lodash.js#L11479

Answer (score 69):

Lets put this baby to bed; tested under Node, Chrome, Firefox and IE 9, it becomes evident that for most use cases:

- **(for...in...) is the fastest option to use!**
- **Object.keys(obj).length is 10 times slower for empty objects**
- **JSON.stringify(obj).length is always the slowest** (not surprising)
- **Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length takes longer than Object.keys(obj).length** can be much longer on some systems.

Bottom line performance wise, use:

```
function isEmpty(obj) { 
   for (var x in obj) { return false; }
   return true;
}
```

or

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
   for (var x in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))  return false; }
   return true;
}
```

Results under Node:

- first result:  `return (Object.keys(obj).length === 0)`
- second result: `for (var x in obj) { return false; }...`
- third result:  `for (var x in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))  return false; }...`
- forth result:  `return ('{}' === JSON.stringify(obj))`

Testing for Object with 0 keys
0.00018
0.000015
0.000015
0.000324

Testing for Object with 1 keys
0.000346
0.000458
0.000577
0.000657

Testing for Object with 2 keys
0.000375
0.00046
0.000565
0.000773

Testing for Object with 3 keys
0.000406
0.000476
0.000577
0.000904

Testing for Object with 4 keys
0.000435
0.000487
0.000589
0.001031

Testing for Object with 5 keys
0.000465
0.000501
0.000604
0.001148

Testing for Object with 6 keys
0.000492
0.000511
0.000618
0.001269

Testing for Object with 7 keys
0.000528
0.000527
0.000637
0.00138

Testing for Object with 8 keys
0.000565
0.000538
0.000647
0.00159

Testing for Object with 100 keys
0.003718
0.00243
0.002535
0.01381

Testing for Object with 1000 keys
0.0337
0.0193
0.0194
0.1337

Note that if your typical use case tests a non empty object with few keys, and rarely do you get to test empty objects or objects with 10 or more keys, consider the Object.keys(obj).length option. - otherwise go with the more generic (for... in...) implementation.

Note that Firefox seem to have a faster support for Object.keys(obj).length and Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length, making it a better choice for any non empty Object, but still when it comes to empty objects, the (for...in...) is simply 10 times faster.

My 2 cents is that  Object.keys(obj).length is a poor idea since it creates an object of keys just to count how many keys are inside, than destroys it! In order to create that object he needs to loop overt the keys... so why use it and not the (for... in...) option :)

```js
var a = {};

function timeit(func,count) {
   if (!count) count = 100000;
   var start = Date.now();
   for (i=0;i<count;i++) func();
   var end = Date.now();
   var duration = end - start;
   console.log(duration/count)
}

function isEmpty1() {
    return (Object.keys(a).length === 0)
}
function isEmpty2() {
    for (x in a) { return false; }
    return true;
}
function isEmpty3() {
    for (x in a) { if (a.hasOwnProperty(x))  return false; }
    return true;
}
function isEmpty4() {
    return ('{}' === JSON.stringify(a))
}


for (var j=0;j<10;j++) {
   a = {}
   for (var i=0;i<j;i++) a[i] = i;
   console.log('Testing for Object with '+Object.keys(a).length+' keys')
   timeit(isEmpty1);
   timeit(isEmpty2);
   timeit(isEmpty3);
   timeit(isEmpty4);
}

a = {}
for (var i=0;i<100;i++) a[i] = i;
console.log('Testing for Object with '+Object.keys(a).length+' keys')
timeit(isEmpty1);
timeit(isEmpty2);
timeit(isEmpty3);
timeit(isEmpty4, 10000);

a = {}
for (var i=0;i<1000;i++) a[i] = i;
console.log('Testing for Object with '+Object.keys(a).length+' keys')
timeit(isEmpty1,10000);
timeit(isEmpty2,10000);
timeit(isEmpty3,10000);
timeit(isEmpty4,10000);
```

Comment: `for (x in a) { return false; }` can be a block-less single statement `for` statement. Meaning, you can save a stack block operation by removing the `{}`.  Kindda, useless information. But might be noticeable with your 6-digit timing accuracy.

Answer (score 32):

Elegant way - use keys

```
var myEmptyObj = {};
var myFullObj = {"key":"value"};
console.log(Object.keys(myEmptyObj).length); //0
console.log(Object.keys(myFullObj).length); //1
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Why has no one commented on this solution? Looks good to me.

Comment: @Vlad This is probably not very efficient. Why ask the JS engine to extract _all_ the keys just to find out if there are _any_ keys

Comment: @VictorGrazi is there any chance the engine might be storing all those keys in memory for easy reference already?

Comment: @adityamenon I would like to know the answer to that myself. Is it in the spec or does it vary between implementations?

Comment: This is 10 times slower for empty objects than using the (for... in) option - see performance tests above.

Comment: The best, short and objetive

Answer (score 23):

```
function isEmpty( o ) {
    for ( var p in o ) { 
        if ( o.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @CMS Stupid IE `:)` At least IE9 corrected that.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: In this solution, you declare `p` in your `for... in` loop with the `var` keyword. If you don't do this, does `p` become an implied global? Just wanted to ask about something that looks like a best practice.

Comment: @parisminton It does in the "default language". However, in strict mode (which is the recommended language), it throws a reference error (unless of course, there already exists a variable with that name in an outer scope). Therefore, you do want to put a `var` there.

Answer (score 22):

```
var x= {}
var y= {x:'hi'}
console.log(Object.keys(x).length===0)
console.log(Object.keys(y).length===0)

true
false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7ona6hz/1/

Answer (score 19):

Surprised to see so many weak answers on such a basic JS question... The top answer is no good too for these reasons:

1. it generates a global variable
2. returns `true` on `undefined`
3. uses `for...in` which is extremely slow by itself
4. function inside `for...in` is useless - return `false` without `hasOwnProperty` magic will work fine

In fact there's a simpler solution:

```
function isEmpty(value) {
    return Boolean(value && typeof value === 'object') && !Object.keys(value).length;
}
```

Comment: I think it's ok to return false on undefined, since undefined is not an object.

Comment: This is 10 times slower for empty objects than using the (for... in) option - see performance tests above.

Comment: In my opinion, this question isn't too basic: because "emptiness" is a very multifaceted thing in javascript - depending on what type of value we're dealing with, we have different conceptions of "emptiness". An Array is empty when it has no items. Even if I say `let a = []; a.v = 'hello';`, most people will agree `a` is "empty". But an Object is empty if it has no properties. Even if we do `let o = { length: 0 };`, most people will agree (I think) that `o` isn't empty because it has a "length" property.

Answer (score 11):

https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty comes in pretty handy:

```
_.isEmpty({})   // true
_.isEmpty()     // true
_.isEmpty(null) // true
_.isEmpty("")   // true
```

Answer (score 7):

How bad is this?

```
function(obj){
    for(var key in obj){
        return false; // not empty
    }

    return true; // empty
}
```

Comment: Actually - this is very good - see performance testing above...

Answer (score 4):

It might be a bit hacky. You can try this.

```
if (JSON.stringify(data).length === 2) {
   // Do something
}
```

Not sure if there is any **disadvantage** of this method.

Comment: If data isn't an object, this could give a false positive for `JSON.stringify([])` or `JSON.stringify("")` or `JSON.stringify(42)`.  That's all I've got though.

Comment: also, I think performance could be worse than using some other method. And JSON.stringify is not available in every browser

Comment: +1 *Excellent answer* + **this is blazing fast solution !!!** Ignore the other comments if your application points to modern web browser engines.

Comment: -1 An overkill for most cases. @cept0 How stringifing an object may be blazing fast?!

Comment: If you like this solution, a tweak like this makes it more explicit. `JSON.stringify({}) === "{}"`

Answer (score 4):

No need for a library.

```
function(){ //must be within a function
 var obj = {}; //the object to test

 for(var isNotEmpty in obj) //will loop through once if there is a property of some sort, then
    return alert('not empty')//what ever you are trying to do once

 return alert('empty'); //nope obj was empty do this instead;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fast onliner for 'dictionary'-objects:

```
function isEmptyDict(d){for (var k in d) return false; return true}
```

Comment: I think this will have better performance: ```isEmpty = function(a,b){for(b in a){break}return !b};```

Comment: I do not see why break, return !b would be better than return false/return true? break and !b both require an extra 'operation'. Minor detail is that b should not be an input variable, but defined inside the function; for (var b in a)... does this, even if a is 'empty'

Answer (score 1):

You can write a fallback if Array.isArray and Object.getOwnPropertyNames is not available

```
XX.isEmpty = function(a){
    if(Array.isArray(a)){
        return (a.length==0);
    }
    if(!a){
        return true;
    }
    if(a instanceof Object){

        if(a instanceof Date){
            return false;
        }

        if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).length == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the objects below:

```
var obj1= {};
var obj2= {test: "test"};
```

Don't forget we can NOT use === sign for testing an object equality as they get  inheritance, so If you using ECMA 5 and upper version of javascript, the answer is easy, you can use the function below:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
   //check if it's an Obj first
   var isObj = obj !== null 
   && typeof obj === 'object' 
   && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]';

   if (isObj) {
       for (var o in obj) {
           if (obj.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
               return false;
               break;
           }
       }
       return true;
   } else {
       console.error("isEmpty function only accept an Object");
   }
}
```

so the result as below:

```
isEmpty(obj1); //this returns true
isEmpty(obj2); //this returns false
isEmpty([]); // log in console: isEmpty function only accept an Object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
funtion isEmpty(o,i)
{
    for(i in o)
    {
        return!1
    }
    return!0
}
```

Comment: works for my 99% cases.

Comment: The `!0` and `!1` are rather confusing here. Why not just simply `true` and `false`?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this decision:

```
var isEmpty = function(obj) {
  for (var key in obj)
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a good way to do it

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.length === 0;
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    for (var i in obj) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return !obj;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
function isArray(a) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'
}
function isObject(a) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === '[object Object]'
}
function isEmpty(a) {
    if (null == a || "" == a)return!0;
    if ("number" == typeof a || "string" == typeof a)return!1;
    var b = !0;
    if (isArray(a)) {
        if (!a.length)return!0;
        for (var c = 0; c < a.length; c++)isEmpty(a[c]) || (b = !1);
        return b
    }
    if (isObject(a)) {
        for (var d in a)hasOwnProperty.call(a, d) && (isEmpty(a[d]) || (b = !1));
        return b
    }
    return!0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Sean Vieira's code to suit my needs. null and undefined don't count as object at all, and numbers, boolean values and empty strings return false.

```js
'use strict';

// Speed up calls to hasOwnProperty
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

var isObjectEmpty = function(obj) {
    // null and undefined are not empty
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if(obj === false) return false;
    if(obj === true) return false;
    if(obj === "") return false;

    if(typeof obj === "number") {
        return false;
    }   
    
    // Assume if it has a length property with a non-zero value
    // that that property is correct.
    if (obj.length > 0)    return false;
    if (obj.length === 0)  return true;

    // Otherwise, does it have any properties of its own?
    // Note that this doesn't handle
    // toString and valueOf enumeration bugs in IE < 9
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) return false;
    }
    
    
    
    return true;
};

exports.isObjectEmpty = isObjectEmpty;
```

Answer (score -1):

here my solution

```
function isEmpty(value) {
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
        return value.length == 0;
    } else if(value != null && typeof value === 'object') {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value).length  == 0;
    } else {
        return !(value || (value === 0));
    }
}
```

Chears

Answer (score -2):

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).length > 0)
{
 alert('obj1 is empty!');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the logic be reversed?

Comment: Yes, more correct would be `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).length < 1`.  Answer as written doesn't work.