# How to check if object is empty?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

So let's `var someObject = { };` how can i detect that object hasnt any properties and methods?

Answer (score 5):

```
function isEmpty(ob){
   for(var i in ob){ return false; }
   return true;
}

isEmpty({a:1}) // false
isEmpty({}) // true
```

Comment: That won't work if someone has added a method to `object.prototype`. Read here http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/

Comment: @xanatos: If "someone" adds to `Object.prototype`, you track it down, remove the offending code, then remove the offending developer.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ In the real world, it is possible to have `object.prototype` extensions. There were even some quite famous libraries that did it (but I don't remember which ones were).... mmmmh an example in this bug report http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1529 and even older versions of the `prototype` library

Comment: @xanatos: That jQuery bug is a great example. You're probably aware that the `json2` library (which was the cause of that bug) no longer extends `Object.prototype` as the original did. Same with `prototypejs`. They both removed the offending code. ;)