# Find the difference between two JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have two JavaScript literal objects below:

```
var obj1 = {
3a5f5c70-58ef-4e4b-8fe0-a271ea2b4f11: true,
9e185ad9-0816-4c5b-ab97-a6c0103d6c22: true,
-K5F-v9lDvZPgDuVhMi3: true,
-K5F-wzH1J01CFXZ9r2c: true,
-K5F-x6H4NXdlwXlolQE: true}

var obj2 = {
-K5F-v9lDvZPgDuVhMi3: true,
-K5F-wzH1J01CFXZ9r2c: true
}
```

I want to find the difference between them so that when I call:

```
var result = findDifference(obj1, obj2);
```

So that the `result` variable would be

```
result = {
3a5f5c70-58ef-4e4b-8fe0-a271ea2b4f11: true,
9e185ad9-0816-4c5b-ab97-a6c0103d6c22: true,
-K5F-x6H4NXdlwXlolQE: true
}
```

I could loop both objects and compare their keys for non-equality or probably convert to then array type first. But I am curious if there is an existing library that is more efficient when the objects grow larger. I have looked at underscore but cant seem to find one that meet my need.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1y3a72rn/

Comment: What if the same keys in both objects have different values? What about nested objects? What about arrays? Does order matter in arrays?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: @sjt003 diff is strictly harder than equals.

Comment: Ignore different values for now. If the key is the same remove it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/22108837/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8431651/139010