# How can I compare two objects and remove duplicates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, for-loop, object

**For example:**

```
let oldData = {user1: {name:'Felix', balance:1000},
                  user2: {name:'Marques', balance:3000}}
let newData = {user1: {name:'Felix', balance:1000},
                  user2: {name:'Marques', balance:2000}}
```

The only thing that changed is user2's balance so how can I get a output like:

```
{user2: {balance:2000}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript JSON comparison/diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357830/javascript-json-comparison-diff)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108837/get-the-delta-of-two-javascript-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431651/getting-a-diff-of-two-json-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Probably a typo but `new` is a keyword and cant be used as object name

Answer (score 1):

Since the objects you want to compare have some depth (inner objects) you can cycle through recursively and build up the differences. The code below seems to do the job.

```js
let old = {user1: {name:'Felix', balance:1000},
                  user2: {name:'Marques', balance:3000, missing: 7}}
let newer = {user1: {name:'Felix', balance:1000},
                  user2: {name:'Marques', balance:2000, extra: 7}}
                  
const findDiff = (o1, o2) => {
  let diff;
  for (const key in o1) {
    const obj1 = o1[key]
    const obj2 = o2 === undefined? o2 : o2[key]
    if (typeof obj1 === 'object') {
      // recursively call if it's an object 
      // unless we know it's undefined in o2 already
      if (obj2 === undefined) diff[key] = obj2
      else {
        const subDiff = findDiff(obj1,obj2)
        // if there's a difference, add it to the diff object
        if (subDiff !== undefined) {
          if (!diff) diff = {}
          diff[key] = subDiff
        }
      }
    } else if (obj1 !== obj2) {
      // for non-objects add to the diff object if different
      diff = {[key]: obj2}
    }
  }
  for (const key in o2) {
    // any keys in o2 that weren't in o1 are also differences
    if (!o1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (!diff) diff = {}
      diff[key] = o2[key]
    }
  }
  return diff
}

console.log(findDiff(old,newer))
```