# Coffeescript isn't empty object

Tags: coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

```
 update: (id, data) ->
    toUpdate = @find(id)
    if toUpdate isnt {}
            console.log "hi mom"
            console.log toUpdate
            toUpdate.setProperty(key, value) for own key, value of data

    return toUpdate

 find:(id) ->
    result = record for record in @storage when record.id is id
    return result or {}
```

Given the following Mocha tests

```
describe '#update', ->
    it 'should return an updated record from a given id and data when the record exists', ->
      boogie = createData()
      archive = new Archive("Dog")
      dog = archive.create(boogie)
      result = archive.update(1, {name:"Chompie", age:1})
      result.name.should.eql "Chompie"
      result.age.should.eql 1
      result.emotion.should.eql dog.emotion

    it 'should return an updated record from a given id and data when the record does not exist', ->
      boogie = createData()
      archive = new Archive("Dog")
      dog = archive.create(boogie)
      result = archive.update(50, {name:"Chompie", age:1})
      result.should.not.exist
```

The result is

```
Archive #update should return an updated record from a given id and data when the record exists: hi mom
{ id: 1,
  validationStrategies: {},
  name: 'Boogie',
  age: 2,
  emotion: 'happy' }
  ✓ Archive #update should return an updated record from a given id and data when the record exists: 1ms
    Archive #update should return empty when the record does not exist: hi mom
{}
    ✖ 1 of 13 tests failed:
    1) Archive #update should return empty when the record does not exist:
    TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProperty'
```

...surprising, isnt it?

Comment: Note, I ended up writing a simple library for Node to encapsulate this concern. If you don't wanna repeat implementing this yourself (test cases are included), check out https://npmjs.org/package/emptyObject

Answer (score 14, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `is` (AKA `==`) is just JavaScript's `===` and `isnt` (AKA `!=`) is just JavaScript's `!==`. So your condition:

```
if toUpdate isnt {}
```

will always be true since `toUpdate` and the object literal `{}` will never be the same object.

However, if `@find` could return a known "empty" object that was available in a constant, then you could use `isnt`:

```
EMPTY = {}

find: ->
    # ...
    EMPTY
```

and later:

```
if toUpdate isnt EMPTY
    #...
```

For example, consider this simple code:

```
a = { }
b = { }
console.log("a is b: #{a is b}")
console.log("a isnt b: #{a isnt b}")
```

That will give you this in your console:

```
a is b: false
a isnt b: true
```

But this:

```
class C
    EMPTY = { }
    find: -> EMPTY
    check: -> console.log("@find() == EMPTY: #{@find() == EMPTY}")

(new C).check()
```

will say:

```
@find() == EMPTY: true
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7JGdq/

So you need another way to check if `toUpdate` isn't empty. You could count the properties in `toUpdate`:

```
if (k for own k of toUpdate).length isnt 0
```

or you could use the special `EMTPY` constant approach outlined above. There are various other ways to check for an empty object, [Ricardo Tomasi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467019/ricardo-tomasi)​ has suggested a few:

1. Underscore offers [`_.isEmpty`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEmpty) which is basically the `for` loop approach with some special case handling and a short circuit.
2. Underscore also offers [`_.values`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#values) so you could look at `_(toUpdate).values().length`. This calls [`map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map) internally and that will be the native `map` function if available.
3. You could even go through JSON using `JSON.stringify(toUpdate) is '{}'`, this seems a bit fragile to me and rather round about.
4. You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of the `for` loop: `Object.keys(toUpdate).length isnt 0`. `keys` isn't supported everywhere though but it will work with Node, up-to-date non-IE browsers, and IE9+.
5. Sugar also has [`Object.isEmpty`](http://sugarjs.com/api/Object/isEmpty) and jQuery has [`$.isEmptyObject`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).

A short-circuiting `for` loop appears to be the quickest way to check emptiness:

```
(obj) ->
    for k of toUpdate
        return true
    false
```

That assumes that you don't need `own` to avoid iterating over the wrong things. But given that this is just a test suite and that an emptiness test almost certainly won't be a bottle neck in your code, I'd go with whichever of Underscore, Sugar, or jQuery you have (if you need portability and have to deal with the usual browser nonsense), `Object.keys(x).length` if you know it will be available, and `(k for own k of toUpdate).length` if you don't have the libraries and have to deal with browser nonsense and aren't certain that `toUpdate` will be a simple object.

Comment: So it checks explicitly for the same reference, not just the same type and value? What's an idiomatic way of checking for empty object...ah, well played. This feels almost evil, but rather delicious `toUpdate.setProperty(key, value) for own key, value of data when ((k for own k of toUpdate).length isnt 0)`

Comment: Would it be "broken" to add `isEmpty()` to `Object.prototype`? I know purists get fussy about messing with the prototype, but it seems really egregious that's not there. Is there a reason not to add it?

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions: I'm not exactly a purist but monkey patching core objects smells bad to me, especially for a generic name like `isEmpty`. You could just grab Underscore and use [`_(toUpdate).isEmpty()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEmpty), Underscore is pretty handy to have around anyway. I'd call that `toUpdate.setProperty(...)` construct rather confusing, a two-liner would be better.

Comment: @muistooshort @VisionarySoftwareSolutions if you're on an environment that supports `Object.defineProperty` there is nothing wrong with extending native prototypes carefully.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi: My main problem is the potential for conflicting monkey patches so I avoid it unless I'm adding something that should already be there or I prefix the names to avoid conflicts; I suppose a lot of that falls under *carefully* though. And `defineProperty` needs IE9+, doesn't it?

Comment: A couple other ways to check, depending on support: `if JSON.stringify(obj) is '{}'`, `if Object.keys(x).length`

Comment: @muistooshort yes, it does, but not everyone is coding for a browser (or all browsers) - this looks like a node app.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi: How portable is `keys` though? The inlined loop is just a quick'n'dirty inlined `keys`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10989/discussion-between-ricardo-tomasi-and-mu-is-too-short)

Comment: I'm actually really interested to see the results in terms of the portability question for Ricardo's proposed snippets as other "answers" to this question, recorded for posterity. Could you add discussion of JSON.stringify() and Object.keys(x).length?

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions: I added some notes and options based on my discussion with Ricardo.