# Empty JS Object

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a better way to check if an object is empty?
I'm using this:

```
function isObjEmpty(obj)
{
    for (var p in obj) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you consider "empty"?

Comment: Why to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) => ref: http://jsfiddle.net/v3Lyn/

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I test for an empty Javascript object from JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking for a one-liner, consider [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var isEmpty = !Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Your current method is dangerous, since it will always return false when `Object.prototype` has been extended: http://jsfiddle.net/Neppc/

Comment: yes. you are right. wating 10min to mark your answer as correct. cant yet. thanks rob.

Comment: This is 10 times slower tha the (for...in) option :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Another option is built into [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/): `jQuery.isEmptyObject(obj)`

Edit: Interestingly, that implementation is the same as your code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a very good way to check if an object is empty!   And it is 10 times faster for exmpty objects than using Object.keys() as suggested above :)

Tested under Node, Chrom, Firefox and IE 9, it becomes evident that for most use cases:

- **(for...in...) is the fastest option to use!**
- **Object.keys(obj).length is 10 times slower for empty objects**
- **JSON.stringify(obj).length is always the slowest** (not suprising)
- **Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length takes longer than Object.keys(obj).length** can be much longer on some systems.

Bottom line performance wise, use:

```
function isEmpty(obj) { 
   for (var x in obj) { return false; }
   return true;
}
```

or

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
   for (var x in obj) { if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))  return false; }
   return true;
}
```

See detailed testing results and test code at [Is object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty/34491287#34491287)