# Does angular.equals() work as an angular expressions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, equality

I'm trying to display a div if an object is non-empty. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23553576/1305516) answer, Im trying to use `angular.equals` to check emptyness, but its not behaving as expected

```js
var test = angular.module('test',[]);

test.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.foo={};
  $scope.bar="bam"
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-show="!angular.equals(foo,{})">{{bar}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The expectation here is that the value of `bar` will only show if `foo` is not equal to an empty object. However, `foo` is clearly set to `{}` and yet `bar` still shows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to access the `angular` object from templates or expressions, you have to make it available on the scope of where you want to use it. In this case you can put it on the `testCtrl`'s scope.

```js
var test = angular.module('test',[]);

test.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.angular = angular;
  $scope.foo={};
  $scope.bar="bam"
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-show="!angular.equals(foo,{})">{{bar}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I generally put utility objects on `$rootScope`, so they're available from everywhere.

Comment: Can you access rootscope from an angular expression?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg you can access anything defined on the rootscope from an angular expression, plus all other scopes inherit from the rootscope. If you change the JS to do `$rootScope.angular = angular;` the example in the answer will behave the same.

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner way would be to only add the angular equals method to the $scope:

```
var test = angular.module('test',[]);

test.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.angularEquals = angular.equals;
}
```

Then you can use the equals method in the template, like:

```
<div ng-show="!angularEquals(foo,{})">{{bar}}</div>
```

Comment: Any downside of this? I mean, why isn't it available already since it seems so common?

Comment: No, no downside. The Angular equals method is not added to the scope by default, to keep the scope small and most of the time the javascript equals suffices.

Answer (score 4):

Your view is looking for a function on the scope, and `$scope.angular.equals` does not exist. You need to write one like this:

```js
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {};
    $scope.bar = "bam";
    $scope.isEmpty = function(obj) {
      return angular.equals(obj,{});
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="isEmpty(foo)">{{bar}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Angular functions can't be used inline, AFAIK.
You could do the equal check with a function inside the controller instead and return the result.