# How to set scope variable inside ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

I want to determine whether any ng-repeated element is rendered.

I write this code

```
<div ng-show="anyRendered">Any has been rendered</div>

 <div ng-show="anyFilterActive">ANY FILTER IS ACTIVE</div>

 <div class="selected-filter-value" ng-if="filter.name && filterCtrl.isActiveFilter(filter)" data-ng-repeat="(name, filter) in filterOptions">
    <span ng-init="anyFilterActive = true;">{{filter.name}}:</span>

</div>
```

But this code doesn't work. Also I try to write $parent.anyRendered inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Can you post filterOptions object

Comment: why dont you just use $index? then you know if smth was rendered and how much https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ng-if

```
<div ng-show="filterOptions.length > 0">Any has been rendered</div>

<div ng-if="filterOptions.length > 0" ng-repeat="(name, filter) in filterOptions">
<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I has more complicated ng-repeat and ng-if already is in ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

You must not write code logic in your templates: all the code must be in your controllers, filters, directives and services. The `ng-init` directive is only here so that you can create aliases to make your templates simpler.

Filters and directives contain "presentation code" and controllers and services contain "business related code".

You could create a filter to know if an object is empty or not ([filter code from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839141/angularjs-checking-if-a-js-object-is-empty-works-with-ng-show-but-not-from-cont/23396452#23396452)), and use it with ng-if, ng-show...

Resulting template:

```
<div ng-if="filterOptions|empty">
     Nothing to show! 
</div>
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in filterOptions">
     {{k}}, {{v}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `$index`

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, filter) in filterOptions">

<span ng-show="$index > 0"></span>

</div>
```

[ngRepeat Docs $index](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

In the example in the ng-repeat docs u can see the usage of $index

Comment: How to use $index > 0 expression outside ng-repeat ?

Comment: $index is only usable in ng-repeat if you need it outside you probably have to write your own filter

Comment: you could only try to pass $index to a function or model value then you would have it elsewhere