# Check if a sparse array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, is-empty

I have a sparse array; that is, an array in which some elements have been `delete`d. Elements are constantly being added and deleted from the middle, so it is *very* large and *very* sparse.

At some point, every element will be `undefined`, but the `length` won't be 0 — so it is empty, but it doesn't express that. How can I check if this has happened?

The best that I can think of is to loop through the whole monster and check if they're all `undefined`. But that would be too inefficient for my application.

Comment: If possible, you could keep a separate counter that keep tracks of the number of elements in the array.

Comment: There is a way to check each element's value without actually looking at each element. But with some more bookkeeping, you could check if the # of elements in the array is 0.

Comment: Are you able to pop values out of the list instead of making them `undefined`?

Comment: You may want to consider using an object (with numeric keys) instead of an array. The only drawback is that you cannot iterate the items in key order.

Comment: @farmerjoe: I use `delete` on a certain index, I don't explicitly set them `undefined`. Since I usually delete from the middle of the array, `pop` is out of the question.

Comment: See my answer for a workaround for this.

Comment: @cybersam: But how would I test for emptiness on that?

Comment: You could also use a `for...in` loop to iterate over the array/array. The run time grow linearly with the number of elements in the array. If you `delete` the elements, there won't be any so the loop won't be executed. Like this `var count = 0; for (var _ in obj) { count++: }`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty

Comment: Why not add a simple if/else before actually utilizing the input? If it is empty, simply do nothing, or call the function again to recheck (basically a loop) but if you just check before using it you rid yourself of any undefined errors.

Comment: Depending on the use-case, the better choice might be avoiding a sparse structure in the first place. They are generally something you want to avoid, except for certain cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions I can think of. Both require some modification to your interactions with the array.

### First solution

#### Keep a counter.

If you simply keep a counter that represents how many elements in the array are *actually there*, then the emptiness check is a mere comparison.

```
var n = 0;

// Adding something to the array:
myArr[2] = somethingDefined;
n ++;

// Removing from the array:
delete myArr[2];
n --;

// Check if empty
if(n == 0) {
   console.log("myArr is empty.");
}
```

### Second solution

#### Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of `delete`

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will actually modify the array instead of setting the values to `undefined`. Example:

```
myArr.splice(2, 1); // Get rid of myArr[2]
```

And this mutates the array and will change `.length` so you can easily check the actual length of the array. Note that `splice` is less efficient (and given you seem to care about the efficiency, the first solution is probably more applicable).

Comment: If you're gonna keep a counter, I would strongly suggest encapsulating this functionality to *enforce* the counter to be in sync. It's too easy to forget it and that can be a real pain in the *** bug.

Comment: Keeping a counter is not technically a solution, but OK. Better than the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the array method **some** that quits when it hits any non falsy value:

`a.some(Boolean);` // returns false if the array has no truthy values

or, if false is a possible value, check for not === undefined:

```
a.some(function(itm){
   return itm !==undefined;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this may not be the most efficient, it does the trick quite succinctly:

```
Object.keys(myArr).length === 0
```

It might be appropriate for less performance-intensive applications.

Comment: That's certainly easier-to-read (and probably write) code, but it is even less efficient than simply iterating over the array.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I was afraid of that. I put it there so it'd be useful to one-liner-hunters in the future.

Comment: @Chris: I just ran [this test](http://jsperf.com/check-if-sparse-array-is-empty) on Chrome and nearly had a heart attack. Object.keys is *faster*! Sadly, this doesn't hold true on Firefox.

Comment: Huh, very interesting! I'm surprised. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Chris: Well, your brute force method is much faster and makes sense. If you only want to know whether the array/object is empty or not, then you can exit the loop once you found the first none empty element.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the removal of your list by using a call to splice:

```
myArr.splice(indexToRemoveAt,nubmerOfElementsToRemove);
```

So for your use case:

```
myArr.splice(indexToRemoveAt,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me sparseArray.size()==0