# HTML 5 and Local Storage Not Null

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I am testing for a condition such that if there are no items in HTML 5 local storage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Cart_items")) {
 //do something....
}
```

If there are no items, it is still displaying

```
1 item in Storage Cart_items="{}"
```

So that my condition is always not NULL..The empty object is treated as an item hence not NULL

How can i write code to know whether Cart_items contains values or not ???

**Update:**

Resolved the issue as follows:

```
function isObjectEmpty(object)
{
var isEmpty = false;
for(keys in object)
{
 isEmpty = true;
 break; // exiting since we found that the object is not empty
}
return isEmpty;
}


var myObject = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("Cart_items") );//object
var isEmpty  = isObjectEmpty(myObject); 
// check if the object is not empty
isEmpty  = isObjectEmpty(myObject); 
if (isEmpty){
//do something
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is object empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

Comment: @koala_dev Thank you for pointing out Is object empty ..Helped me in right direction..