# show and hide in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem Question -

I am trying to use ng-show and ng-hide but I don't know where I am making mistake.When my object is empty it is not hiding the div.

Can someone please guide me on this is much appreciated

//this is my view

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div ng-show="show">
      Show me as json object is not empty
 </div>
 <div ng-hide="show">
     hide me as my json object is empty
 </div>
</div>
```

//my controller

```
 myCtrl();

        function myCtrl() {
            Service.getMoney()
                .success(function (data) {
                    if(data !=null || data != 'undefined'){
                        $scope.data = data;
                        $scope.show= true;
                        console.log(cart);
                    }
                    else{
                       $scope.show= false;
                   }
                })
                .error(function (status, data) {
                    console.log(status);
                })
        };
```

Please guide me where I am making mistake. Also my json(data) is coming like this (Object {}) if it is empty

Update answer: It was nothing to do with ng-show and ng-hide. I have to just check my json object
`if (data.value)` // Thanks to @shomz

Comment: Is that your full code? Also, `"but does not do what I need"`... we don't know what you need.

Comment: Are you sure your getMoney() function was called? Do you have log messages in the browser console?

Comment: @demas yes it is getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your response comes as an empty object, then `if(data !=null || data != 'undefined')` won't work - it will always be true.

In fact, that condition will ALWAYS be true, because **no** object can be a null and 'undefined' at the same time.

Your Angular part seems fine, but you need to fix your JS conditions. The simplest fix would be to modify your service to return false it there is no data.

See how it's always true:

```js
alert({} != null || {} != 'undefined');
```

Comment: what is the way to check for the empty object in angular? I tried different things but no luck so far. thanks

Comment: Nothing related to angular here, it's a plain js issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty?lq=1

Comment: The easist way would be to return false, or to check against something you know it's there after a successful call. Say, you know you'll have `data.json` in a successful call, then you simply check for it: `if (data.json) {...`

Comment: There's no point in checking for null unless you're really returning null from the service when there's no data. If you really don't want to modify your service, use one of the functions from the link I gave you to check for an empty object.

Comment: i have to check for null to hide the div.

Comment: Not for `null` unless your service returns `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66701/discussion-between-geekongadgets-and-shomz).