# mongoDB: remove empty objects in an object-array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Unfortunately I got some false objects in an array in some documents, which are structured like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "8vJY4baMbdYkgHian",
    "title" : "Cars",
    "tradename" : [
        {

        },
        {
            "element" : "Audi"
        },
        {
            "element" : "Mercedes"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in this example, the first object in the array is empty. How can I remove empty objects in all `tradename`-arrays of all documents in the collection?

```
Collection.update(
    { 'tradename': {} },
    { $pull: { 'tradename.$': '' } }
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is object empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following update operation using **[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/pull/)** updates all documents in the collection to remove empty objects from the array `tradename`, given that the embedded document has the `element` property only:

```
db.collection.update(
    { },
    { "$pull": { "tradename": { "element": { "$exists": false } } } },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

Comment: this my remove elements if that object does not have 'element' property

Comment: @Azzi That's why I said explicitly _given that the embedded document has the element property only_

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach to remove empty objects from an array with no assumptions:

```
db.a.update(
    {"tradename": {}},
    { $pull: { 'tradename': {$in:[{}]} } },
    { "multi": true }
);
```