# Check if an Obj is Empty Array

Tags: javascript

Is there some native/lodash/underscore/etc method to check if an obj is an empty array? `[] === []` returns false due to different obj references. I wrote a quick checker for it:

```
  function isArrayOfLength(obj, length) {
    var isArrayOfSpecifiedLength = false; 

    if(Array.isArray(obj)){ 
      if(obj.length === length){
        isArrayOfSpecifiedLength = true; 
      }
    }

    return isArrayOfSpecifiedLength; 
  }
```

but I don't want to clutter up production code if something better is available. [Plunk if you want it for whatever reason](https://plnkr.co/edit/sjgnVoNAI0KUNCwhbdpx?p=preview). Note - I need to be able to check any var type - the method might get an obj or an int, so I can't just check length without verifying that it's an array.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty

Comment: @djaszczurowski Yea, I saw that, but it looks like it will pass for an object as well... "Returns true if an enumerable object contains no values (no enumerable own-properties)."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is object empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

Comment: @canon: I am focused on anything that distinguishes between an empty array and anything else, without throwing.

Comment: `Array.isArray(myArray) && myArray.length === 0`

Comment: (function(){
        var obj = {lol: 'test'};
        var isArray = obj.length; 
        console.log(isArray); 
      })(); returns undefined Raj.

Comment: @Rajesh Though I guess undefined is falsy, and it's fine since it doesnt throw, so that might be the best solution.

Comment: @canon doesn't the answer contain everything that is asked?

Comment: @VSO is the expected parameter an `array` or `array || object`

Comment: @Rajesh array || object

Comment: @canon: The latter.

Comment: @canon thanks for the explaining. I have delete my answer and have marked it as duplicate. Just a pointer tough, **Please comment** if you downvote. This will ensure your message is conveyed. I missed you conversation and was unaware about duplicate. Still thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's super-simple:

```
function isEmptyArray(obj) {
   return Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var ap = (Array.isArray(obj) && (obj.length === 0))? true : false;
```

if ap evaluates to true then you will know its an empty array

Comment: Both `Array.isArray(obj)` and `(obj.length === 0)` will return a boolean value. You **do not** need a ternary operator.

Comment: Yes both will return a boolean and the 2 booleans will then be evaluated eg
true && false = true. true && true will evaluate to true thus giving us what we wanted to know in the first place

Comment: Yes both will return a boolean and the 2 booleans will then be evaluated eg
true && false = true. true && true will evaluate to true thus giving us what we wanted to know in the first place.
The ternary operator is more precise

Comment: What your expression will look like `return true? true : false` or `return false? true : false`. So instead of again evaluating, you can return output of expression.

Comment: No @Rajesh. Javascript will evaluate the entire expression in one go and the whole thing will be solved in just one line of code.
Try it out in your console. I just did

Comment: @EdwinKato the ternary operator is totally unnecessary in this case. You could simply write `var ap = Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 0;`. The entire right side of that assignment is already a boolean expression. Sure, your version functions, but it's doing extra work and it's more verbose than it needs to be. Raj is right. I'm not sure what you're arguing here.

Comment: Oooh i see. Your explanation is clearer. Thanx @Canon and i get it now

Answer (score -2):

With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) you can use `R.isArrayLike([]); //=> true` to check if it's an array, and `R.isEmpty([]);          //=> true` to verify if has data.