# Check if an object is equal to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to check if an object has a child object array

for example

```
{
   "parent_category_id": "ABC",
   "parent_category_name": "ABC COMPANY",
   "place_id": 733,
   "industry": {
       "@nil": "true"
   }
   "street_id": 733
}
```

How would you check if the "Industry" object would have a child array.
Like if "Industry" has a child array value of "@nil: true". Then alert Has Child

Comment: i see no array.

Comment: your `object.industry` is a plain js object not an array. It is not clear what you are looking for?!

Comment: @Martijn: That's for the OP to fix. The misunderstanding of what's what may be the crux of the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your quesion, what array are you expecting? And `@nil: true` is not an array value, it's an attribute of an object of type boolean or string in your code snippet.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi: same comment as I made to Martijn: Don't change the wording of the question. The misunderstanding there may well be the reason for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with the `instanceof` operator.

For example:

```
var t = {
    "parent_category_id": "ABC",
    "parent_category_name": "ABC COMPANY",
    "place_id": 733,
    "industry": {
        "@nil": "true"
    },
    "street_id": 733
};
```

After it, you can use:

```
t.industry instanceof Object // result is: true
t.industry instanceof Array  // result is: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check if an object has children and is not empty you can either do an `IF` statement like:

`if (obj.industry) {}`

or like this using the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)` method which will return the names of all properties within an object:

```js
var obj = {
   "parent_category_id": "ABC",
   "parent_category_name": "ABC COMPANY",
   "place_id": 733,
   "industry": {
       "@nil": "true"
   },
   "street_id": 733
};
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj.industry);

names.forEach(name => console.log('Property/Value ->', name, obj.industry[name]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
info = {
  "string": "ABC",
  "array": [1, 2, 3],
  "object": {
    "key": "value"
  },
  "object(empty)": {},
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array)) {
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

for (var i in info) {
  if (isEmpty(info[i]) == false) {
    console.log(info[i]);
  }
}
```

Reference: [Is object empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994201/is-object-empty)

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.isArray(parentobj.industry)
```

if you meant to check if it is an array or not