# How to match an empty dictionary in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, match

From the node REPL thing,

```
> d = {}
{}
> d === {}
false
> d == {}
false
```

Given I have an empty dictionary, how do I make sure it is an empty dictionary ?

Comment: You might consider using a library such as [check-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-types).  In which case, you could use `check.emptyObject(d)`.

Comment: Here is a more up-to-date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: `JSON.stringify({}).length -2 ? true : false`

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```

Comment: Only in newer browsers. For the record, the keys property is only supported in IE >= 9 [reference](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)

Comment: I'd be amazed at JavaScript lacking this basic functionality, if I weren't so used to it by now.

Comment: Here is a more up-to-date answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 21):

How about using jQuery?

```
$.isEmptyObject(d)
```

Answer (score 19):

You could extend `Object.prototype` with this `isEmpty` method to check whether an object has no own properties:

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    for (var prop in this) if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Wow ..I find it rather interesting that javascript lacks this "basic" functionality

Comment: Extending the Object.prototype can create problems iterating over the object later http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/

Comment: This interferes with jquery

Comment: test in react js, but output `Object.prototype.isEmpty: this= undefined`, so not work, how fix this?

Answer (score 12):

Since it has no attributes, a `for` loop won't have anything to iterate over. To give credit where it's due, I found this suggestion [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=193474).

```
function isEmpty(ob){
   for(var i in ob){ return false;}
  return true;
}

isEmpty({a:1}) // false
isEmpty({}) // true
```

Comment: I would create a count(obj) function and isEmpty would eval if count equals 0.

Comment: You might want to check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(i)` before returning false. This filters out properties inherited through the prototype chain.

Answer (score 10):

This is what [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) uses, works just fine. Though this does require the jQuery script to use [isEmptyObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/).

```
isEmptyObject: function( obj ) {
    for ( var name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Example
var temp = {};
$.isEmptyObject(temp); // returns True
temp ['a'] = 'some data';
$.isEmptyObject(temp); // returns False
```

If including jQuery is not an option, simply create a separate pure javascript function.

```
function isEmptyObject( obj ) {
    for ( var name in obj ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//Example
var temp = {};
isEmptyObject(temp); // returns True
temp ['b'] = 'some data';
isEmptyObject(temp); // returns False
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm far from a JavaScript scholar, but does the following work?

```
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(d).length == 0) {
   // object is empty
}
```

It has the advantage of being a one line pure function call.

Comment: cool solution! it is actually the only one without loops and without invoking third-party libraries

Answer (score 3):

If performance isn't a consideration, this is a simple method that's easy to remember:

```
JSON.stringify(obj) === '{}'
```

Obviously you don't want to be stringifying large objects in a loop, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var SomeDictionary = {};
if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(SomeDictionary))
// Write some code for dictionary is empty condition
else
// Write some code for dictionary not empty condition
```

This Works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to check that it was of type 'object' like so:

`(typeof(d) === 'object')`

And then implement a short 'size' function to check it's empty, [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array).

Answer (score 0):

If you try this on Node.js use this snippet, based on this code [here](http://onemoredigit.com/post/1527191998/extending-objects-in-node-js)

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "isEmpty", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
            for (var prop in this) if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```