# How do I check this boolean hashmap is empty in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)
>   [How do I test for an empty Javascript object from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json)

```
var abc = {};
console.log(abc=={}) //false, why?
```

Why is it false? How do I match a blank hash map...?

Comment: {} is a new object. So abc !== "a new object" because abc is another object

Comment: I want to match: Is "abc" a blank hash map.

Comment: @Ikke I think this is not a duplicate of that one. Here we have an interesting point about an empty object.

Answer (score 4):

{} is a new object instantiation. 
So abc !== "a new object" because abc is another object.

This test works:

```js
var abc = {};
var abcd = {
  "no": "I am not empty"
}

function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (var o in obj)
    if (o) return false;
  return true;
}

console.log("abc is empty? " + isEmpty(abc))
console.log("abcd is empty? " + isEmpty(abcd))
```

Update: Just now saw that several others suggested the same, but using hasOwnProperty

I could not verify a difference in IE8 and Fx4 between mine and theirs but would love to be enlightened

Comment: How does checking the `typeof abc` help with knowing if it is an empty object?

Comment: @nnnnnn please see update and other answers testing for properties in the object

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is needed to differentiate between properties inherited from the prototype chain (which should not make the object "not empty"), and own properties. When you write a function, you might not want to use it only on `{}` :).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (abc.toSource() === "({})")  // then `a` is empty
```

OR

```
function isEmpty(abc) {
    for(var prop in abc) {
        if(abc.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc = {};
```

this create an object

so you can try the type of:

```
if (typeof abc == "object")...
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `var abc = {};` creates a new (empty) object and points the variable `abc` to that object.

The test `abc == {}` creates a second new (empty) object and checks whether `abc` points to the *same* object. Which it doesn't, hence the `false`.

There is no built-in method (that I know of) to determine whether an object is empty, but you can write your own short function to do it like this:

```
function isObjectEmpty(ob) {
   for (var prop in ob)
      if (ob.hasOwnProperty(prop))
         return false;

   return true;
}
```

(The `hasOwnProperty()` check is to ignore properties in the prototype chain not directly in the object.)

Note: the term 'object' is what you want to use, not 'hash map'.