# Given two javascript objects, how can I determine what field(s) were changed?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two versions:

```
let oldObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 43
}

let newObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 44
}
```

In the case `age` changed.

Comment: Firstly, change `new` to something else and add commas after the location lines. Then you can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432188/3885376 .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to only track changes (of primitive values) and not additions/deletions, you can just iterate over the values from one object and do direct comparisons with corresponding values in the other object:

```js
let oldObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 43
}

let newObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 44
}

let changes = Object
  .entries(oldObj)
  .filter(([key, value]) => value !== newObj[key])

console.log(changes)
```

If you don't care about the values, you can just filter the keys instead:

```js
let oldObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 43
}

let newObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 44
}

let changes = Object
  .keys(oldObj)
  .filter(key => oldObj[key] !== newObj[key])

console.log(changes)
```

If you want to include additions/deletions, you can first determine the object with the larger amount of keys and do similarly to above:

```js
let oldObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 43
}

let newObj = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 44,
    addition: 'test'
}

let [larger, smaller] = Object.keys(oldObj).length > Object.keys(newObj).length
  ? [oldObj, newObj]
  : [newObj, oldObj]

let changes = Object
  .entries(larger)
  .filter(([key, value]) => !smaller.hasOwnProperty(key) || value !== smaller[key])

console.log(changes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooray for [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)!

```
var changes = _.reduce(oldObj, function(result, value, key) {
    return _.isEqual(value, newObj[key]) ?
        result : result.concat(key);
}, []);
console.log(changes);
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should do is to edit your question, and replace `new` with something else, because new is a keyword in javascript used with constructor functions to create an instance of that particular constructor function.

```
let old = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 43
}

let _new = {
    name: "john",
    location: "usa",
    age: 44
}
for ( let j in old ) {
    if ( old[j] !== _new[j] ) {
        console.log(`${old[j]} is not ${_new[j]}`);
    }
}
```

the below code loops through the `old` object, the content of j will be the keys of the old object, the if statement uses `old[j]` to get the content of the `j` key ( same thing applies to `_new[j]` ), the if statement also checks if the content and the type of `_new[j]` and `_old[j]` is the same. If you don't care about the types , you should remove one of the equal signs in the if statement