# Facebook FQLproblem with javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

**Hey everyone,**

i do the following query to get a user statuses:

```
FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT message FROM statuses WHERE uid = ' + userId
    },
    function(data) {
        //    do something with the response
    }
```

);

It works great when the number of result are more than 0.

but when there are no results, the callback function is not called at all.

i need to know if there are 0 rows returning from this query, is there any way to do it?

**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `statuses` table **does not** exists. You should be using [`status`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) table.

The callback is always called but you should properly check against [empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/679937/337227). Just paste this on the [Javascript Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/):

```
<fb:login-button scope="read_stream">
    Grant access to statuses
</fb:login-button>

<button onclick="getStatuses()">Get Statuses</button>
<script>
window.getStatuses = function() {
    FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = me() AND time < 315532800'
    },
    function(data) {
        if(!isEmpty(data)) {
            for(var key in data) {
                var obj = data[key];
                console.log(obj['message'])
            }
        } else {
            console.log("data is empty")
        }
    });
};

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
</script>
```

Here I am checking for statuses *before* 1/1/1980 to insure that an empty result is returned. In your console you should note the `data is empty` response.

Answer (score 0):

When there are no results from a query, you should be getting an empty array.

Also, there isn't a FQL table named "statuses",  it's "status".