# Skip tweets with links, replies or hashtags when getting them with JSON and jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I'm developing a website where a user enters a random word and gets a list of related tweets.

How can I exclude tweets containing links, replies or hashtags when fetching them with json?

Here's my jQuery code:

```
        <script>

        function go(){
          var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=results&q=" + $("#text").val();
          $("<script/>").attr("src", url).appendTo("body");  
            $("#text").remove();
        }

        $("#text").keydown(function(e){ if( e.which == 13 )  go(); });

        function results(r){
          window.results = r.results;
          window.theIndex = 0;
          displayNext();
        }
        function displayNext(){
          if( window.theIndex >= window.results.length ){
            return;
          }
          $('.content').remove();
            $('.helper').remove();
          createDiv( window.results[window.theIndex] );
          window.theIndex++;
          setTimeout(displayNext, 4000);
        }

        function createDiv(status){
          var tweets = status.text;
          $("<span class='content'>")
          .html(tweets)
          .appendTo("body");
          $("<span class='helper'>")
          .appendTo("body")
        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According the the [Dev Twitter API reference](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search), the JSON object that is returned contains a `result` attribute, which is an array of JSON objects representing all the tweets. The two attributes in these JSON arrays of particular interest are the `entitites` attribute and the `to_user_id` attribute. So to check if the tweet is not a reply and does not contain any links you would check if `entities` is an empty object and `to_user_id` is null.

Changing your `displayNext` function to this should work:

```
function displayNext(){
    if( window.theIndex >= window.results.length ){
        return;
    }
    $('.content').remove();
    $('.helper').remove();
    var result = window.results[window.theIndex];
    if (Object.keys(result.entities).length !== 0 && result.to_user_id === null) {
        createDiv( window.results[window.theIndex] );
        window.theIndex++;
        setTimeout(displayNext, 4000);
    }
}​
```

(Note that I'm using the answer from [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json) to check if `entitites` is an empty object.)