# Javascript Checking Variable

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I test for an empty Javascript object from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json)

```
var test= {};

var incidentReport = {
      "place1": "n/a",
      "place2": "n/a",
      "place3": "n/a",
 }
```

Above are the two ways my varible is going to look. Ive tryed doing the following code to test if its empty/looks like {}

```
if(test == "")
```

and tried

```
if(test == null)
```

also tried

```
if(!test)
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong? Just a beginner to JavaScript and JSON. Is what I am doing considered back practice are there better ways to declare this empty?

Thanks for the support

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length == 0`.

Comment: Your question is a dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json, which has two excellent answers

Comment: @RobW. Then why jQuery implemented it this way: `isEmptyObject: function( obj ) {
  for ( var name in obj ) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 },
 `

Comment: @gdoron I would be happy to know why... Please tell if you find the answer to this question.

Comment: @gdoron because jQuery explicitly refuses to work with code that modifies `Object.prototype` http://docs.jquery.com/Won't_Fix#Object.prototype_Issues

Comment: @gdoron jQuery is designed to be cross-browser compatible. [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_support) is not available in FF 3.6, <IE9 and Opera <12. These browsers are still commonly used.

Comment: @gdoron "Introduced in JavaScript 1.8.5" is not relevant. JS 1.8.5 means nothing in a non-Firefox browser.

Comment: This  should not of been closed, got alot better answer here then i did in the link you provided

Comment: @user983969 the answers here are copy pasted from the duplicate question... I don't know how to deal with that. I don't like it.

Comment: @RobW. The link does. Anyway, it's a dup comment... :)

Comment: Yes but ive also been explaiend to be where i was going wrong by @Eswar Rajesh Pinapala

Comment: So ive learned, not just copied and pasted stacker overflow code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(test == "")
```

checks if it is an empty string, so this won't work

```
if(test == null)
```

checks if it is `null` which is "similar" to `undefined` - this isn't the case

```
if(!test)
```

checks if it is a falsy value, this in not the case either.

You have to check if there exist child-elements (properties):

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if ( isEmpty(test) ){...}
```

The very important point is the `.hasOwnProperty()` - this checks if it is a real property of the object and not only inherited through the prototype chain.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble both? It explains why his attempts fail and gives a solution. Feel free to upvote me:-D

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON.stringify

```
var test= {};
if(JSON.stringify(test).length==2)
alert('null')
```

Comment: +1 this is really neat. But i could imagine that this is very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

test here is an object. so you have to check if there are any prioperties/elements int his object. You can try something like below

```
var test= {};

function isEmptyObject(obj) {
   // This works for arrays too.
   for(var name in obj) {
       return false
   }
   return true
}

alert("is this object empty?" + isEmptyObject(test));​
```

Comment: Execute `Object.prototype.foo='bar';`, and your function will always return `false`.

Comment: The question here is to make OP understand how to detect an empty object, Its ok if it fails when a non empty object is passed.

Comment: @RobW. Why would you do that?!

Comment: @gdoron I added the note as a warning. There's no sane reason to extend the `Object`'s prototype like that.