# I've declared an array of empty elements, how can I check which elements remain empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, properties

As title says, I have the following array:

`var viewModel = [{}, {}, {}];`

At some point in my code I may populate the 2nd element:

`var viewModel = [{}, { "test" : "value" }, {}];`

I need a way of evaluating if the elements are empty or not. In the above case, elements 0 and 2 will evalute to true, and element 1 will evaluate to false.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried comparing each element to `undefined` and `' '` to no avail. I know could probably check for the `test` property of each element (if it exists it's not empty) but I ideally wanted a way of determining this independent of any property names.

(I've tagged jQuery as I'm open to jQuery suggestions).

Comment: Your code probably isn't working as the array element contains an empty object, it isn't empty or undefined. You might want to look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/ or the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: @Joe - Brilliant!! Exactly what I was after. Please post as the answer and I'll mark accordingly. Thanks very much mate.

Comment: It's ok, I'd just be re-posting what someone else had put. Glad it helped you though!

Answer (score 1):

```
{} === {} //false

JSON.stringify({}) === JSON.stringify({}) //true

JSON.stringify(myArray[0]) === JSON.stringify({}) //true
```

This might come handy in your particular case may be. I havent thought much about the loopholes also.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
// function to check if object is empty
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

var viewModel = [{}, { "test" : "value" }, {}];
// loop
for(var i = 0; i < viewModel.length; i++)
{ 
    // returns true if empty, otherwise false
    console.log(isEmpty(viewModel[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the elements that are in each object by looping through the array.

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
  if(Object.keys(test).length == 0){
    //element array[i] is empty!
  }
}
```

This is only in browsers supporting Ecma-script 5.

Answer (score 0):

Takes an array of objects and returns a new array of true/false values

```
function isObjectEmpty(arr) {
  return arr.map(function (el) {
    return Object.keys(el).length === 0 ? true : false;
  });
}

isObjectEmpty(yourExampleArray) // [true, false, true]
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/852E9/1/)