# Access multidimensional dictionary in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm working on a project in **AngularJS**.

I have **JSON** as

```
{
  "leagues":{
    "aLeague":{
      "country":"aCountry",
      "matchs":{
        "aUniqueID1":{
          "date":"2014-09-07 13:00:00",
          "guest_player":"Me",
          "host_player":"Tom",
          "odds":{
            "guest":"2.80",
            "host":"2.25",
            "null":"2.85"
          },
          "score":"0 - 0"
        },
        "aUniqueID2":{
          "date":"2014-09-07 18:30:00",
          "guest_player":"Bryan",
          "host_player":"Me",
          "odds":{
            "guest":"3.25",
            "host":"1.98",
            "null":"2.95"
          },
          "score":"0 - 0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to display it `guest_player`and `host_player`in a `ng-repeat`.

But I'm not able to access to `aUniqueID1` or `aUniqueID2`.

Any ideas?

Comment: ngrepeat with `(key, item) in obj.leagues.aLeague.matchs` etc...

Comment: It's tough to know what you're trying to do here. Is it possible to set up a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here:http://jsbin.com/wekow/1/edit

```
<p ng-repeat="(key, item) in data.leagues.aLeague.matchs">
Guest Player :{{item.guest_player}}<br/>
Host Player :{{item.host_player}}
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks it's working :-) last things, do you know how can I check if `matchs` is empty ?

Comment: @user1269586 when do you want to check that ?

Comment: @user1269586 please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: @sss @Josep Here :   `<ul class="list" ng-repeat="match in lesMatchs"><li class="item" ng-repeat="(key, item) in match.matchs">{{item.host_player}} vs {{item.guest_player}}</li></ul>` . (`lesMatchs` = `data.leagues`)

Comment: @user1269586 Object.keys(data.leagues.aLeague.matchs).length?"not empty":"emptpy". Object.keys(data.leagues.aLeague.matchs) will retrieve an array with the keys of "data.leagues.aLeague.matchs"  , therefore in your case Object.keys(data.leagues.aLeague.matchs).length will retrieve the number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, item) in data.leagues.aLeague.matchs">
<span>User ID: {{key}}</span>
<span>Guest Player: {{item.guest_player}}</span>
</li>
```

The first span will display the `key` of the item (the value that you were asking about), the second one the attribute `guest_player` of the item.