# How can I tell if an object is empty?

Tags: javascript

I hope this makes sense. If I have an object:

```
 var a = {"minlength":true}
 var a = {}
```

How can I tell if the object is empty (the second line of code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object.keys(a).length === 0
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for undefined as well:

```
if (a != undefined) {
    // object is defined, you can do stuff now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(a)` returns a list of keys, so `Object.keys(a).length == 0` means it's empty.