# How to append new JSON element to JSON_array?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var taskArrObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json"));
var newJsonObj = {xx:true, yy:"bbb", zz:"10."};
```

var updatedJsonObj = taskArrObj + newJsonObj ???
append JSON array with new JSON element?

```
res.json(updatedJsonObj);//send splitted JSON array in response
```

Comment: JSON.push(newJSONObject)

Comment: If `taskArrObj` is an array then use `taskArrObj.push(newJSONObject) `

Comment: whats the format of `tasks.json`?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: whats the format of tasks.json? >> that's simply file: [{xx:true, yy:"bbb", zz:"10."} , {xx:true, yy:"bbb", zz:"10."}]

Comment: Add a `console.log(taskArrObj)` and tell us what the result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
var updatedJSON=taskArrObj.push(newJsonObj);
```

Comment: It means your taskArrObj is empty, possibly task.json could not loaded into it

Comment: Do you mean task.json file cannot be blank? So how data gonna consists empty task.json file?

Comment: Yes you are trying to call push method on a object that does not exist. This is the error. Graham has given a explanation why task.json may not be loading

Comment: So can I create empty JSON variable if my JSON file is empty?

Comment: Thats just error checking. You can do that. If you specify encoding then file contents will be available in your variable

Comment: function readJsonContent() {
  fs.readFile('tasks.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    taskArrObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", "utf8"));
  });
}

Comment: how can I check if my file is empty?

Comment: Already good answer for that availabe: [Check if JSON is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: I added checking for Exceptions: try{
      taskArrObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFile("tasks.json"));
      return true;
    }catch (err) {
      return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.readFileSync):

> If encoding is specified then this function returns a string.
>   Otherwise it returns a buffer.

`readFileSync` returns a buffer if you don't specify an encoding. `JSON.parse` will only accept a `String` as a parameter. Pass an encoding in:

```
var taskArrObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", "utf8"));
taskArrObj.push(newJsonObj);
```

Comment: How to convert my {xx:true, yy:"bbb", zz:"10."} to newJsonObj? for normally pushing into array ..