# Check if struct is empty: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of items showing up on a page, using a struct. If a customer doesn't choose on of those items, I want to check if the struct is empty or not.

Here is my code:

```
shopItems.shopItemsStruct = {};
```

so when I do `console.log(shopItems.shopItemsStruct)` when I don't select a item, it shows me `Object { }`. How do I check in an if statement (ie if shop items are not selected)?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it look like if there is an object selected?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: Object { 24: Object} and Object { 24: Object, 25: Object} if it has more items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of keys in the object it is passed as a parameter. If the returned value is zero then the object has no keys.

```
if (Object.keys(shopItems.shopItemsStruct).length === 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an object; a key value set. Just look for the presence of keys.

```
if( !Object.keys(shopItems.shopItemsStruct).length ){
 //no shop items selected                            
}
```