# How to check if the value is an empty array?

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "livingroom": [],
  "bedroom": [],
  "study": [
    {
      "name": "s0",
      "thumbnail": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/0/small_istagingViewer/sig@staging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/螢幕快照 2016-03-29 下午2.12.32.png",
      "web": "https://storage.googleapis.com/peterbucket/istagingViewer/sigstaging.com.tw/Cuiti/study/web/201603292.12.32.png"
    }
  ],
  "outdoor": [],
  "other": [],
  "id": "-KE5spXGRjC_9WSIh_eN",
  "name": "Cuiti",
  "categoryCount": 1,
  "panoramaCount": 1
}
```

I want to only exclude the `[]`s. I tried `value.length > 0` but that throws an error because some of the values aren't arrays.

What's the best solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: `if (value.length && value.length > 0) // code here`

Comment: @JonathanBrooks i'm still getting the error: `Error when evaluating expression "keyIsVisible($key) && (value.length && value.length > 0)". 
vue.common.js?e881:3386 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: Oh I see, you'll have to check the value isn't undefined instead then. Like `if(typeof value !== "undefined") // continue here`

Comment: use if(typeof(temp.livingroom) ==! undefined) ... before checking for length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your sample is not JSON, it's a Javascript Object. In order to remove empty arrays from this object, you can simply check it like this

```
for(var key in yourObject){
    var value = yourObject[key];
    if(Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0){
        delete yourObject[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.isArray()` to check if something is an array:

```
if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length > 0) { }
```

And use this polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) if needed:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    Array.isArray = function(arg) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `constructor` property to check whether value is array or not and then check length of value

```
for(var key in items){
    var value=items[key];
    if(value.constructor===Array && value.length === 0){
        delete items[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator

```
function isArray(value) {
    return value instanceof Array;
}
```