# Different ways of defining unassign variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I know when we want to define unassign variable in Javascript we can do:

```
var p;
```

and the other:

```
var p ={};
```

i want to know differences between these two ways, and if i define a variable in second way it is not null! what is the value in the variable, if we want using it in a `if` condition, for example :

```
var p ={};
if(p=='what i shout put there')
  {}
```

Comment: `{}` is an object. Of course it's not null.

Comment: `var p = {}` is not an unassigned variable. You assigned an empty object to it.

Comment: Try `var p = {}; console.log(typeof p);`

Comment: @t.niese if i want using it in a `if` condition, how can use it?

Comment: [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: And beside that `p` is not `null` if your write`var p;`. It is of type `undefined`. So `p !== null`  but `p === undefined`.

Comment: Depends what you want to test for. If you want to know that it is an `object` then you test for `typeof p === 'object'`. If you wand to know if two variables point to the same object: `var p = {}; var q = p;` then you test `p === q`.

Comment: @t.niese thank you. the link that you sent me was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

`var p` is creating an unassigned variable. So `console.log(p)` will log `undefined`

`var p ={};` is a way of creating object using [`literal notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Object p have methods like `constructor`,`hasOwnProperty`,`toLocaleString` etc

> if(p=='what i shout put there'){}

If it is required to check if `p` is an object then below snippet is useful

```
if(Object.prototype.toString.call( a ) === '[object Object]'){
 // Do rest of code
}
```

An object can have properties. like

```
var p={};
p.a ="someValue";
```

In this case you can check by

```
if(p.a  === 'someValue'){
     // Do rest of code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = {};
```

It is not unassigned ,it is infact assigned to the empty object

If you do below , it will be trut

```
if(p) {} // truthy
```