# Node.js server: get body from POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, server

I have created a server with node.js and express.js but if I send a POST request and try to check the body, it always says the body is empty. Here is my code:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 61000);

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {

    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Server runs on port %s', port);

});
```

routes/routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {        

     app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
          res.status(200).json({"response": "Hello!"});    
     });     

     app.post('/', function (req, res) {

         if (req.body != null) {
             res.status(200).json("Success");
         }

         res.status(200).json("Error");
     });
};
```

If I do a POST request now on www.hurl.it and add a body with a text like "Test", it gives me the response "Error", but it should give me the response "Success", because the body is not null.

And if I add the "body-parser" module to my app like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

it gives me "Success" even if I let the body empty. If I return req.body the response is: {} and if I add a body it is also {}

Someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its always hitting the error case.
Try this:

```
if (req.body != null) {
  res.status(200).json("Success");
} else {
  res.status(200).json("Error");
}
```

Comment: Adding to this and empty hash `{}` is a valid body. So you might want to check that a hash is not empty. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: Still not working. And why it gives me an empty hash {} if I have added something to the body?

Comment: I am sending the request with www.hurl.it/ and this is the location from my node server: [http://eis1617.lupus.uberspace.de/nodejs/](http://eis1617.lupus.uberspace.de/nodejs/)

Comment: Make sure you are adding them in the right order. AKA the body parser needs to be one of the first things added to the app:

Comment: `var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var router = express.Router();`

Comment: Yes I have it in that order.

Comment: Besides wrapping it in the if/else I am not sure. I am sorry I couldnt be of more help

Comment: what is the client side call and how do u verify that you actually get a json msg 'on the wire' ?  Depending on the client imple , if you OMIT the "Content-type" header or incorrectly have MME header instead of 'app-json' hdr for content-type, you may not be sending a json msg when u think that u r. Test client side with 'curl .... -d '{ your-json-here }'

Comment: Another idea try this: `res.status(200).json(req.body);` That'll give you some good debug info

Comment: res.status(200).json(req.body); this gives me: {} like I said. Even if I add a body it is {}. But thanks for your help. @Robert Rowntree, With Client you mean where I send the request from? Like I said before, I send it from www.hurl.it and I dont add any headers.

Comment: When I send the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and pass it some json looking data i can get it to spit the body back out

Comment: Well hower it works now when I add content-type application/json to the header. Thank you guys :)