# Request Body Empty with Express Body Parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I'm currently using body-parser to try and receive POST data but my request body returns an empty object. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Does anyone know what the issue with my code might be?

Here's my code:

```
// Script intialized by Gulp
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Import registration and login functionality from database.js
const database = require('./database')

// Configuration
let jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
app.use(jsonParser)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../docs')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../src')))

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', 'src/pages')

app.listen(app.get('port'))
console.log('Listening on port: ' + app.get('port'))

// Routing
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Welcome!')
    res.render('index');
})

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Uhh, it looks like something went wrong here')
    res.end()
})

// Link with database.js to link username and password attributes
app.post('/login', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log(req)
    console.log(req.body)
    //database.login('ThisIsATestAccountBoi', 'TestPassword')
    //console.log('Username: ' + username + '\n' + 'Password: ' + password)
    res.end()
})
```

Comment: Code seems fine, how are you posting the data ?

Comment: @adeneo I submit my form data with the DOM's .submit() method.

Comment: Well, you're expecting JSON as the only data, as you've used the `jsonParser` directly in your route, so if you're submitting a regular form as    `x-www-url-form-urlencoded` it's clearly not sending just JSON, is it

Comment: @adeneo I actually used the enctype='application/json' to set the data so it doesn't actually have to be. That's just the default. Thanks for the suggestion though :P

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have to be? you have a route like `app.post('/login', jsonParser, function(req, res) {` where `jsonParser` is middleware that parses a JSON request object and populates `req.body`, if the data sent isn't purely JSON, the parser fails, and `req.body` is empty ?

Comment: @adeneo Hmm, even when I just go with the typical url-encoded bodyParser it returns empty though. Do you think it could be an issue with my form? I removed the enctype.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Node.js server: get body from POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306797/node-js-server-get-body-from-post-request/40306891?noredirect=1#comment67875523_40306891)

Looks like they were missing the Content-Type header. Send the request with the header **Content-Type** = **application/json**

Comment: Nah I don't think that was the issue. I used res.setHeader() with the appropriate arguments and it still returns an empty object. I'll keep searching though!

Comment: Not in the server code. Set the header in the request you are sending (from whatever tool you are using ex: Postman)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue. It was an issue with my Jade tabbing. The way I had it tabbed made it so that my form closed on itself without having any components inside of it. Sorry for the inconvenience!