# javascript - check if object is empty

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create to javascript/jquery test to check if my object is empty and cannot figure it out.

Here is the object when it has something in it:

```
{"mergedSellerArray":{"key1114":"1120"}}
```

And here is the object when empty:

```
{"mergedSellerArray":{}}
```

This is the current test I have based on another SO answer but it does not work:

```
var sellers = JSON.stringify({mergedSellerArray});
if(Object.keys(sellers).length === 0 && sellers.constructor === Object) {
    console.log("sellers is empty!");
}
```

Comment: what is `sellers`?

Comment: If `sellers` is the outer object, then it *isn't* empty, and you'll have to write some code to check that it matches your expected state.

Comment: What's the point of testing the constructor?

Comment: added in the sellers declaration

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` turns the object into a string, as the name suggests. What's the point of the `sellers` variable anyway? Why can't you just check `mergedSellerArray` as is?

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify` part and check `mergedSellerArray` object.

Comment: @JJJ you were right.  I should have included the sellers declaration in my original question.  I didn't even think about the fact that my sellers was no longer a json object after that stringify command.

Comment: check out this similar post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You were testing `sellers` which is not empty because it contains `mergedSellerArray`. You need to test `sellers.mergedSellerArray`

```js
let sellers = {
  "mergedSellerArray": {}
};
if (Object.keys(sellers.mergedSellerArray).length === 0 && sellers.mergedSellerArray.constructor === Object) {
  console.log("sellers is empty!");
} else {
  console.log("sellers is not empty !");
}
```

Comment: Downvoted for performance. The entire object is mapped to an array with the use of `Object.keys`, which takes `O(n)` or worse (depending on hash implementation), which imo is pretty irresponsible for a simple "isEmpty" check. An `O(1)` implementation: `let hasNoKeys = obj => { for (let k in obj) return false; return true; }`

Answer (score 4):

Here is in jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var obj={"mergedSellerArray":{}};
  alert("is empty: "+$.isEmptyObject(obj.mergedSellerArray));

  var obj2={"mergedSellerArray":{"key1114":"1120"}};
  alert("is empty: "+$.isEmptyObject(obj2.mergedSellerArray));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" />
```

jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/nyqgbp38/

Comment: The entire jQuery library to test if an object is empty?!

Comment: It is mentioned that  the solution in jquery. thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are using lodash library, you have an elegant way to check an empty object, array, map or a set.
I presume you are aware of ES6 Import statement.

```
import {isEmpty} from "lodash"

let obj = {};
console.log(isEmpty(obj)); //Outputs true.

let arr = [];
console.log(isEmpty(arr)); //Outputs true.

obj.name="javascript";
console.log(isEmpty(obj)); //Outputs false.
```

So, for your code,

```
isEmpty(mergedSellerArray); //will return true if object is not empty.
```

Hope this answer helped.

Answer (score 4):

This will work in modern web browser. **It is quite easy and simple**

```
const empty = {};
if(Object.keys(empty).length === 0 && empty.constructor === Object) {
    console.log("Object is empty");
} else {
    console.log("Object is not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can create the helper function :

```
const isEmpty = inputObject => {
  return Object.keys(inputObject).length === 0;
};
```

Can use it like:

```
let inputObject = {};
console.log(isEmpty(inputObject))  // true.
```

and

```
inputObject = {name: "xyz"}; 
console.log(isEmpty(inputObject)) // false
```