# Javascript ES2015 check if one of the named key in an object is empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks like below

```
process:Array[3]
0:Object
    office_id:""
1:Object
    office_id:6
2:Object
   office_id:""
```

I want to check if office_id named key is not empty

If I find at least one office_id that is not empty it will return true else if all is empty it will return false.

The default value of office_id is empty string as you can see.

The object is dynamic since I'm using some input select form to add another object with office_id so if they select something another object will be added with office_id equal to that specific select id.

Now, as for validation purpose I need to check if the object process contains an office_id with a numeric value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - check if object is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813784/javascript-check-if-object-is-empty)

Comment: none of those objects are empty, they all have a propery called `office_id` - though, reading between the lines ... `process.some(i => i.office_id)` will be true if at least one object in the `process` array has a non-falsey `office_id` property - however, an `office_id:0` would not count as "truthy" ... so .. perhaps ... `process.some(i => typeof i.office_id === 'number')`

Comment: `[{office_id:""}, {office_id:""},{office_id:""}].some(obj => typeof obj.office_id === "number")`, but you should first decide what "office_id is empty" actually means: empty string only? missing? undefined? null? 0? NaN? date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple for loop and more efficient way

```
function () {
  for(i = 0; i < process.length; i++){
    if (process[i].office_id){
      return true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Using ES5 filter

```
function () {
  var filteredProcess = process.filter(function(pr) {
    if (pr.office_id){
      return true;
    }
  });

  return filterProcess.length ?
    true: 
    false;
}
```

Comment: `if(filteredProcess.length)
  {return true;}
  else{ return false }` ... or `return !!filteredProcess.length` (possibly don't even need the `!!` if `truthy`/`falsey` is good enough as opposed to `true`/`false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) combined with the javascript [truthy-ness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) to determine if it's empty. Since 0 evaluates to falsey, you need to handle that as a special case. See `isEmpty` below

```js
const isEmpty = (arr) => arr.some(item => item.office_id === 0 || !!item.office_id);

// This returns false because all the elements are falsey
console.log(isEmpty([
  {
    office_id: "",
  },
  {
    office_id: undefined,
  },
  {
    office_id: null,
  },
  {
    office_id: "",
  },
]));

// This returns true because the number 6
console.log(isEmpty([
  {
    office_id: "",
  },
  {
    office_id: 6,
  },
]));

// This returns true because 0 is special cased
console.log(isEmpty([
  {
    office_id: "",
  },
  {
    office_id: 0,
  },
]));
```

Comment: would `typeof item.office_id === 'number'` be an appropriate test instead?

Comment: but wouldn't `typeof item.office_id === 'number'` always be the same truthy/falsey as your condition? (just thought it was simpler, that's all - your logic is fine)

Comment: No, `"foo"` would return `true` in my code, and `false` in the typeof check. (Which isn't to say that one is more right than the other, depends on what is desired)

Comment: ahhh, yes of course - I was looking at the OP's code with blinkers on :p

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.some` to verify that at least one member of the array matches your condition:

```
const result = yourArray.some(item => item !== '')
```