# JavaScript/Angular 1 - Test if an object is defined and empty it if true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to test if an object is empty, then empty it but only if true

With something like that :

```
angular.isDefined(this.project.motivation.description) = {}
```

The problem is that `angular.isDefined` return a boolean.
Is that it has a method with good practice without used the conditions if, with Lodash or ES2015 for example ?

Comment: Why does it have to be fancy like that? Readability is more important that not using an `if` condition

Comment: You want to empty an object, but only if it is empty?! How is that? If it is empty, why would you empty it (if it is already is empty)? What am I missing here?

Comment: @lealceldeiro No I want the emptied when it is not defined

Comment: OK, the title suggests that, but not so the body of the question, you should edit it.

Comment: Sagi, maybe this answer help you: [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Lodash with _.defaultTo() function:

```
var f = {a: "test"}
f = _.defaultTo(f, {})
```

If the object is undefined, the function return the empty object.