# How to check emptiness with single condition regardless of input is object or array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a conditional statement which execute if an input is not empty but the issue is that input can either object or array.

```
if(response && response.length > 0 ) {
 // but this failed if response is an object
}
```

So I am looking for single condition which check for both (object and array) in one line. Moreover, I checked that `typeof` of array and object are *object*

```
        var object_ = {};
        var array_ = [];
        console.log('typeof object', typeof object_); // object
        console.log('typeof array', typeof array_); // object
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: not duplicate; I am seeking for a single method of object and array checking

Comment: Check my answer. It works for both object and arrays

Comment: Given Array is also an Object, you can simply use: if (response && response instanceof Object)

Comment: @XihuaDuan No, the question if, how can he check if an object is empty when it's both array or object in one condition

Comment: I see, but answer#2 has a flaw as well, please read my new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple solution

```
if(response && Object.keys(response).length > 0) {
 //works for both object and arrays
}
```

Check this code snippet

```js
       var obj1 = {};
       var obj2 = {
          'test1':'test1',
          'test2':'test2'
       };
       var arr1 = [];
       var arr2 = ['a','b','c'];

       console.log(obj1 && Object.keys(obj1).length > 0);

       console.log(obj2 && Object.keys(obj2).length > 0);

       console.log(arr1 && Object.keys(arr1).length > 0);

       console.log(arr2 && Object.keys(arr2).length > 0);
```

Comment: Why would you need jquery?

Comment: This is super simple. but no need of jQuery

Comment: No, this answer has a flaw that it will treat a string as a valid input.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(Object.keys(response).length)
```

Simply check if there are keys in the object.

Note that Object.keys will return the following:

```
{} => []
{a:undefined} => ["a"]
[] => []
["a"] => [0]
"a" => [0] //strings are arraylike
undefined => Error
```

Comment: but what if array comes as input?

Comment: @pro.mean `Object.keys()` works on arrays. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I do not agree this answer. Check my answer , you need to compare the key length with greater than 0.

Comment: @AKA no you don't.

Comment: @aka so then i downvote yours too because i *think* its wrong ? ( hint : it isnt)

Comment: Did you check the code snippet @Jonasw which i added

Comment: @AKA Your edit nor your snippet changes anything to your statements here

Comment: Check properly. My answer and the snippet works as expected. I do not think it is something to be down voted.

Comment: @aka train station

Comment: @Jonasw What you mean?

Comment: @Jonasw gives error when i have 

var response;
Object.keys(a).length
But mine do not

Comment: Thank you for useful demonstration as well

Comment: You see that when response is undefined there is no condition that checks undefined in his answer. It simply checks the Object.keys(undefined).length. So you people say this is correct. Wow suprising

Comment: That is understandable @AKA

Comment: because he also demonstrate with various scenario including undefined and string input

Comment: Lets see, his answer was first, the OP asks for 1 condition, it gives it, OP didn't specify what the behavior should be when nothing is there, and Jonas did specify it, but most of all, he was quite relaxed in this topic, so he won the popularity vote ;)

Comment: @aka by the way, i didnt downvote your answer. And yes, the upper code fails in some cases, but if one trys to pass undefined aka nothing, the OP may wants to check that additionally, or if there always should be passed an object its quite okay to throw an error i think

Comment: @icepickle thanks :) ( actually im not calm at all ...)

Answer (score 1):

Answer 2 could not tell a string from Array or Object, just run this:

```
let s = 'hello, world';
console.log(Object.keys(s).length); // 12 will be the output
```

A revision should go as:

```
if (response instanceof Object && Object.keys(response).length > 0)
```