# use ng-if for empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

if to disable a button based on condition.
 i am getting empty object initially so i need to disable the button below is my code:

```
<button class="btn-reg btn btn-primary" title="Create Book from Collection"
        ng-click="scenariosViewAll.saveBookData();" 
        ng-disabled="scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject == {}">Create Book from Collection
</button>

vm.collectionBookObject in controller
```

if i console the object i am getting:
{} so i am using above condition.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: Consider using form controls to enable/disable the create button. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Binding to form and control state](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state). And [AngularJS `<form>` Directive API Reference - Submitting a form and preventing the default action](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action).

Comment: You can try until object 'null': ng-disabled="scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject == {} || true"

Answer (score 0):

`scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject == {}` will always be false because objects in javascipt are compared by reference.

You need to play it smarter on this.

your object `scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject` could be initialised to a null value. That way, your condition would simply be `ng-disabled="!scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject"`.

If for any reason, you cannot initialize your object to a null value, you can check if there is a key in your object : `ng-disabled="!Object.keys(scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject).length"`

Comment: ng-disabled="!Object.keys(scenariosViewAll.collectionBookObject).length  
 is disabling but enable is not happening if i get data

Comment: you should try using immutable objects. If you just add properties into your object, angular won't know you updated the object, and won't trigger a digest on the view. If you need more information, can you add the code where you initialize and update your object into your question?