# Check object key has empty value

Tags: javascript

I have object & its key empty value;

like `var obj = {newData : {}};`

I want to put if condition that return true or false. how can I check that obj.newData has empty object or not?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {newData : {}};
const obj2 = {newData : {x: 'x'}};
const isEmpty = testObj => Object.keys(testObj).length === 0;
console.log(isEmpty(obj.newData));
console.log(isEmpty(obj2.newData));
```