# Check if JSON response data is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The JSON response looks like this when it is empty when viewed in the browser console:

```
{"data":{},"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://url/form/BN217473","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

In angular script I am checking if the response is empty but the check is not catching the empty response as the logic block is never executed

```
if (response.data == '') {
    console.log("no data found");
}
```

How can I check that my response is not empty?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108184/965834 ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try below code snippet:-

```
if(!Object.keys(response.data).length){
     console.log("no data found");
 }
```

If you are getting data as empty object like data: {}, then you should check if there is any key inside the object or not.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Content is `{}` but the check fails. Length is 2.

Comment: OK, you have to use an object and not a string. So `JSON.parse(someString)` is your friend. But `JSON.parse()` can fail ...

Comment: If you want to use single method for checking strings and json strings for null or empty, you can try this:
public static boolean isNotNullOrEmpty(Object str) {
        if (str == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if ("".equals(str)) {
                return false;
            }else if("{}".equals(str)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 3):

You can check the number of keys/properties with  `Object.keys(response.data).length === 0` or less efficiently with `JSON.stringify({}) == JSON.stringify(response.data)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if your response is not empty try :

```
    if ( json.length == 0 ) {
    console.log("NO DATA!")
}
```

But i advice you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) and his `isNil()` method or `isEmpty()` to check if your object is empty or null or undefined.

Cheeers