# Validate empty object

Tags: javascript

I have an variable that devolves an empty object, and i need validate thas this variable have a value.

```
guardar: function() {
    var value1 = Ext.getCmp('radio1').getValue();

    if (value1 === {}) {
        alert('It is necessary to select an option.');
        return;
    } 
}
```

When it arrives in the debug line in the If statement, although the value of the variable is {}, when evaluating the condition the result is false.

¿Someone could help me about how can i do that validation?

Comment: you can get the length of a list of keys on the object. `Object.keys(value1).length`, === failed because it's checking identity, and the two objects are not the same object.

Comment: Check the extjs documentation on how `.getCmp()` works, what it returns and how to determine if the returned component has a "value"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a object, then, do you need to proccess that object to verify if exist a property 
Try this:

```
guardar: function() {
    var value1 = Ext.getCmp('radio1').getValue();

    if (typeof value1 === 'object' && Object.keys(value1).length === 0) {
        alert('It is necessary to select an option.');
        return;
    } 
}
```

Comment: typeof's are lower case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this

Comment: I found other way to do it: if (Ext.Object.isEmpty(value1)), what do you think?

Comment: I don't think so those `isEmpty` is a native function of Object prototype, but you can make a function with that name, and assign to Object.prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `value1 === {}` for the same reason that `{} === {}` is false. The reason for this is javascript compares objects by reference, not by value. Which means it checks if the objects occupy the same memory location.

You can try something like

```
Object.prototype.isEmpty = function() {
    for(var key in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you can test if it's empty

```
if (value1.isEmpty()) {
    alert('It is necessary to select an option.');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to call an empty object. If its strictly `{}`, then this doesn't suffice. `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY.isEmpty()`, for example, returns `true`. But then again, this may be good enough. I would avoid extending built-in objects though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

```
    function isEmpty(obj) {
        for(var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    var x = {};

   if(isEmpty(x)){

     alert('It is necessary to select an option.');
     return;

   }else{


   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

```
guardar: function() {

var value1 = Ext.getCmp('radio1').getValue();

if (Object.keys(value1).length === 0) {
    alert('It is necessary to select an option.');
    return;
 } 
} // This Will Work as your requirement
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm going to try this