# How to delete empty objects from an Array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting array like below.

```
[{},
 {},
 {},
{ label: '2015', showLabels: '1,' },
 {},
 {},
 {},
{ label: ‘2017’, showLabels: '1,' }]
```

but, I would like to delete empty indexes.

I have tried following to delete. But, Not working as expected.

```
const filteredFinalYearArr = yearArray.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
});
```

**Note:** This is dynamic data

Any suggestions?

Comment: [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object) - In this thread you will get full brief about how to check empty object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) all the objects which have non-zero number of `keys`:

```js
let yearArray = [{},{},{},{label:'2015',showLabels:'1,'},{},{},{},{label:'2017',showLabels:'1,'}]

let filtered = yearArray.filter(el => Object.keys(el).length)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/_g3x9q/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-empty) about best ways to check if an Object is empty.

```js
const years = [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  { label: '2015', showLabels: '1,' },
  {},
  {},
  {},
  { label: '2017', showLabels: '1,' }
]

const hasValues = obj => {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) return true
  }
  return false
}

const filteredYears = years.filter(y => hasValues(y))

console.log(filteredYears)
```

Comment: *"Object.keys(obj).length is not supported on Firefox < 4 and IE < 9"* Neither are arrow functions. OP is using react native. So, they will have traspilers or polyfills to support old browsers :)

Comment: @adiga oh yeah. thanks for pointing out. serves me right eh? :-D

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build the array.

```js
const yearArray = [{},{},{},{label:'2015',showLabels:'1,'},{},{},{},{label:'2017',showLabels:'1,'}]

const filteredFinalYearArr = yearArray.reduce((o, i) => {Object.keys(i).length > 0 && o.push(i); return o}, [])

console.log(filteredFinalYearArr)
```