# Angular check json has children or empty

Tags: json, angular

Want to check child and child variables or empty

```
{{ CustomJsonSchema?.properties | json }} // if empty returns {}
{{ CustomJsonSchema?.properties | json }} // if not empty returns { "street_1": { "type": "string" }, "zip_code": { "type": "string" }, "first_name": { "type": "string" } }
```

HTML :

```
<div>Has Elements</div>
<div>Empty</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

While this approach will work, it will unnecessarily trigger the `isEmpty` function on every change detection even if there are no changes to the object. For a more efficient approach, follow @Chellapan's method.

---

You can create a function in your component to check if your object is empty and use it in your template.

```js
isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
}
```

Depending on the ECMAScript version or whether you are using a third-party library like `lodash` or `underscore`, you can check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object) for the different ways to check if an object is empty.

Then in your template

```html
<div *ngIf="CustomJsonSchema?.properties && isEmpty(CustomJsonSchema.properties)">
    Empty
</div>
<div *ngIf="CustomJsonSchema?.properties && !isEmpty(CustomJsonSchema.properties)">
    Has elements
</div>
```

The first condition is to make sure `CustomJsonSchema.properties` exists before checking if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom pipe. Then use ngIf else directive to show different elements in html

**isEmpty.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'isEmpty'
})
export class IsEmptyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let keys = value && Object.keys(value);
    return Array.isArray(keys);
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="CustomJsonSchema | isEmpty else noData">
  has Value
</div>
<ng-template #noData>
   Empty
</ng-template>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipe-c)

Comment: Please don't use function call in template,It will cause an unnecessary change detection therefore it will cause performance issue. Be aware of it.