# delete empty object inside nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i've an array

```
const exampleArray = [
    {
     id: 1,
     name: test
    },
    {
     id: 1,
     name: test
    },
    {
    },
]
```

now the array `exampleArray` live inside another array of objects so

```
const exampleNest = [{
    property1: {},
    property2: [],
    exampleArray: [{...}],
}]
```

I need to remove the empty object inside `exampleArray` and return the rest of the array.

I already tried to use filter

```
const noEmptyObjects = exampleNest.filter(({ exampleArray }) =>
    exampleArray.filter(attachment => attachment !== {}),
  );
```

i tried too `Object.keys(attachment).length !== 0` instead of `attachment !== {}` but i continue to receive the array with the empty item.

Comment: This is not a valid JS:

`


i've an array
```const exampleNest = [
    property1: {},
    property2: [],
    exampleArray: [{...}],
]
```
Did you mean an Array, or an Object?

Comment: `attachment !== {}` will *never* return `false`

Comment: thanks for the correction, it was an array of objects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use simple https://stackoverflow.com/a/32108184/3932166 to check empty object and for array with this one.

```
exampleArray.filter(attachment => (condition from above link));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your array by checking if the object has an id property

`exampleArray.filter(function(obj) { return obj.hasOwnProperty("id"); })`

Answer (score 0):

Because of {} is object. So, {} == {} always false.

```
exampleArray.filter(attachment => JSON.stringify(attachment) !== "{}")
```