# IF-ELSE CONDITION NOT WORKING IN JSX REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to execute an if condition in JSX  in foolowing way

```
{
                        ((selectedWebsite != null) && (selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt != null) &&
                            (typeof selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt !== "undefined")) ?
                        <FormControlLabel style={{"margin-left": "auto"}}
                                          control={<Switch size="small"
                                                           checked={selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt.enabled}
                                                           onChange={handleCheckDesktop}/>}
                        /> :
                        null
                    }
```

now `selectedWebsite` is {} and desktop_prompt is undefined but still executing the if condition and i am getting the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined**. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Check for undefined should not be in String. So instead of  desktop_prompt !== "undefined" check desktop_prompt !== undefined.

Comment: tried it, still same error

Comment: Your provided condition as well as suggested solutions should work. There must be some other problem or maybe you are accessing .enabled somewhere else in code.

Answer (score 0):

Since selectedWebsite is an [empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object), you can do a check for keys length rather than checking empty object is `undefined` or `null`:

```
{Object.keys(selectedWebsite).length !== 0 ? 
  <FormControlLabel
    style={{"margin-left": "auto"}}
    control={<Switch size="small"
                 checked={selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt && selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt.enabled}
                 onChange={handleCheckDesktop}
              />}
  /> : null}
```

Comment: tried it but still no luck, still getting the same error. i have consoled Object.keys(selectedWebsite).length but it is still executing the code but i should execute null instead

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
{
                    selectedWebsite && selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt ?
                    <FormControlLabel style={{"margin-left": "auto"}}
                                      control={<Switch size="small"
                                                       checked={selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt.enabled}
                                                       onChange={handleCheckDesktop}/>}
                    /> :
                    null
                }
```

Comment: tried it but still no luck, still getting the same error. i have consoled Object.keys(selectedWebsite).length but it is still executing the code but i should execute null instead

Comment: can you please mention in the question the value of `selectedWebsite` ?

Comment: only way the code is running is `selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt ` has a value that is neither `null` or `undefined`

Comment: i have mentioned it its an empty object {}.

Comment: i have logged the value of  selectedWebsite and selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt in console and its {} and undefined

Comment: check here https://jsbin.com/gomekuliyu/edit?js,console . check the console. its behaving just like i said. I think you are missing something else

Comment: i think `selectedWebsite.desktop_prompt` value changes after a while which in term make the condition valid and execute the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219911/discussion-between-sazzad-and-shoaib-iqbal).