# React - value of prop not ready when passed to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page that displays the details of a `meeting` and a button to edit it. The button opens up a modal that has the meeting object passed to it like so:

```
<AddMeetingModal
    show={isEditing}
    cancel={closeEditModal}
    edit={meeting}
/>
```

and in the model I have a `useEffect``which checks

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(props.edit) {
            //Fill input fields with values from meeting object
        } else {
            //Set all fields to blank for adding a new meeting
        }
    }, [props])
```

The error I'm getting comes when the inputs are trying to be filled `cannot read value __ of undefined` obviously because on the first page, the meeting isn't loaded right away, so how can I wait for it to be loaded before calling the modal. I've tried using turnery operators, being more specific in the if statement above and just can't wrap my head around it.

Also the meeting initially is being fetched via Redux hence why it isn't loaded intially.

```
const meetingDetails = useSelector(state => state.meetingDetails)
const { loading, error, meeting } = meetingDetails
```

useEffect for Modal component

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(!!props.edit) {
            setMeetingHeld(props.edit.meeting_held)
            setMeetingType(props.edit.meeting_type)
            setAdd1(props.edit.location.address_line_1)
            setAdd2(props.edit.location.address_line_2)
            setAdd3(props.edit.location.address_line_3)
            setTownCity(props.edit.location.town_city)
            setCountyState(props.edit.location.county_state)
            setPostCode(props.edit.location.post_code)
            setCountry(props.edit.location.country)
            setTime(props.edit.meeting_time)
            setHeldWith(props.edit.held_with)
            setDetails(props.edit.details)
            setExistingConnector(props.edit.existing_connector)
            setConnectorComments(props.edit.connector_comments)
            setCompetitor(props.edit.competitor)
            setMeetingReason(props.edit.meeting_reason)
            setFollowUpActions(props.edit.follow_up_actions)
            setFollowUpDate(props.edit.follow_up_date)
        } else {
            setMeetingHeld('scheduled')
            setMeetingType('in_person')
            setAdd1('')
            setAdd2('')
            setAdd3('')
            setTownCity('')
            setCountyState('')
            setPostCode('')
            setCountry('')
            setTime('')
            setHeldWith('')
            setDetails('')
            setExistingConnector(false)
            setConnectorComments('')
            setCompetitor('')
            setMeetingReason('')
            setFollowUpActions('')
            setFollowUpDate('')
        }
    }, [props])
```

Comment: I'll add the useEffect for it

Comment: You can a) exit the useEffect function if the props aren't ready b) use conditional rendering in your JSX if other stuff isn't ready

Comment: can you console log props.edit in useEffect and share output here?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela Initially it is an empty object, then when the meeting has been fetched, it is an object containing the meeting data

Comment: @BranOIE If it is initially empty and you are checking `!!props.edit` then it will be true because there props.edit is not null or undefined.

Comment: @PriyankKachhela So how can I check if it is not an empty object

Comment: Maybe this answer better explains how to check for empty object. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `Promise` that only shows the modal when the meeting is ready.
If you don't have the data right away, `async` is the best way to go about this.

Comment: I understand what you mean but not sure where to apply the async/await