# How to make input box readonly conditionally in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inputbox

How do I make an input box readonly conditionally? I have a state value I want to check and if it is empty, I want the input box prop of readonly to be added to the input box. This is my implementation of this so far:

```
<Input title={ 'Node Type'} name={ 'nodeType'} inputtype={ 'text'} placeholder={ 'Type node type name'} readonly={this.props.updateCards === {}} />
```

*edited question to say I want to check if it is empty rather than true based on comment reply

Comment: `this.props.updateCards` will never `=== {}`. Do you want to check if it's empty? Or if it's some other value?

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant if it is empty. I phrased my question wrong. It's default state is empty and that's the case when I want the readonly prop added to the input box

Answer (score 2):

you can do this like:

```
<Input readonly={this.props.updateCards ? true : false} />
```

Comment: sorry, I meant when props.updateCards is empty, not true.

Answer (score 0):

If it's empty you can use this like below. For an implementation of what `isEmpty` would look like, see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

```
return (
    <Input
      title={ 'Node Type'} 
      name={ 'nodeType'} 
      inputtype={ 'text'}
      placeholder={ 'Type node type name'} 
      readonly={isEmpty(this.props.updateCards)} 
    />
)
```