# the handleSubmit function doesn't work in if sttaement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code everything is ok but if statement doesn't work
if i erase the if part of code the request works just fine but when it's inside of if it does't work
my errors object is empty

```
 const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate(values))

      if (!errors) {
          console.log(errors);
          baseUrl.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
            baseUrl
              .post("/api/v1/admin-login", values)
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch((err) => {});
          });
     }
```

and the errors state

```
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the `validate` function?

Answer (score 0):

that's because the value of error is not changed yet.

you can fix it in this way

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    const errors = validate(values) 
    setErrors(errors)

      if (!errors) {
          console.log(errors);
          baseUrl.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
            baseUrl
              .post("/api/v1/admin-login", values)
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
              })
              .catch((err) => {});
          });
     }
```

Comment: still the same 
it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The value has not changed yet because you set errors for the update state in the current function and the next line you want to use.
You can use the local variable in the function to check errors.

setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this. state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
e.preventDefault();
const errors = validate(values) 
setErrors(errors)
  if (!errors) {
      console.log(errors);
      baseUrl.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((response) => {
        baseUrl
          .post("/api/v1/admin-login", values)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {});
      });
 }
```

Comment: still the same 
it doesn't work :(

Comment: what does `validate(values)` return?

Comment: yes it returns just fine
the request part doesn't work
but without setting a condition it woks just fine

Comment: if your `validate(values)` returns empty object `{}` and if you try to check `!errors` it will always returns false. To check if object is empty then you can use `isEmpty` method from lodash or underscore library or you can create your own function to check if object is empty or not. Check this answer for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: thank you iman i didn't know that
it works know ;)