# checking undefined or null in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, user-interface, jestjs, nestjs

I have below method in `nestjs`.

```
async findOne(userId: string) {
        const user = await this.userRepository.find({userId});
        if (user) {
            throw new NotFoundException(`User does not exist`);
        }
        return user;
        
    }
```

this method retunrn an `array of object`. if value not found in DB it return `[{}]`.
I need to throw exception when it return `empty array` I mean `[{}]`. for that I need to put `condition` in `if` block
when I write `user`, or `user==null` or `user.length==o` in `if` block , in all the case it is not going inside the `if`

what modification I need to do in `if` block?

Comment: so check for an empty array or an object that is empty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: actually it is array of Object. so if it returns one object or empty object in both the case result is not null or undefined. so none of the condition in mentioned answer is matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to check if `user` is an array with length = 1 where the first element is an empty object. You can do something like this:

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.find({ userId });
if (
  !user ||
  user.length === 0 ||
  (user.length === 1 && Object.keys(user[0]).length === 0)
) {
  throw new NotFoundException(`User does not exist`);
}
return user;
```

You will need to look into your `userRepositoy.find()` function to see if there are any other possible values it could return. From your description, it either returns an array of users or an array with a single empty object. However, there may be other failure cases where it returns something different. That part is up to you to make sure you handle those cases properly.

Comment: this will be true if it returns one object which is not empty.  `user.length === 1`

Comment: If `user` is `[{someKey: someValue, ...}]`, then this will not throw an exception because `Object.keys(user[0]).length` will not be 0.

Comment: I reformatted the code so that the logical operators are a little easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering why you actually need to use `find` method.

You are trying to get a user based on `userId` in usersRepository, isn't userId supposed to be unique?

If it's unique then you are getting either an empty array as you described or with only one object in it. Not sure what DB you are using but in any case, `findOne` method should be there.

It this applies to your case `findOne` should do the trick

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ userId });
if (!user) throw new NotFoundException(`User does not exist`);

return user;
```

Or if you have to use `find` and you want to make if statement more readable I suggest using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isEmpty), [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#isEmpty) or any similar library to keep it cleaner.

With Ramda you could do as following

```js
const [firstUser = {}, ...others] = await this.userRepository.find({ userId });
if(R.isEmpty(firstUser)) throw new NotFoundException(`User does not exist`);

return [firstUser, ...others];
```

I highly assume that fetched data based on `userId` is just one record so I believe you can use just like this

```js
const [user = {}] = await this.userRepository.find({ userId });
if(R.isEmpty(user)) throw new NotFoundException(`User does not exist`);

return user;
```