# I'm struggling with the proper vernacular for searching, but how can I remove all keys with empty/null/undefined values from a flat object?

Tags: javascript, object, filter

```
  {
        "Gender": "male",
        "SiteId": -99,
        "LastName": "Bobby",
        "BirthDate": "2000-01-15T06:00:00.000Z",
        "FirstName": "Ricky",
        "HomeLocation": {},
        "ClientCreditCard": {},
        "CustomClientFields": {}
    }
```

I've tried a few options I found here, but can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried:

```
let o = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((k) => obj[k] != null)
  .reduce((a, k) => ({ ...a, [k]: obj[k] }), {});
```

and

```
var output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Also, any recommended courses that focus on data manipulation for arrays/objects would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there examples where those objects might hold properties or will they always be empty?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for filtering out `null` (first snippet) and `undefined` (first and second snippet) values. All you need is to add a [test for empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/679915/1048572) as well.

Comment: @Andy Yes.  If they have properties then I need them to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

This will give you an array that looks like this:
`[[key, value], [key, value], [key, value]]`

From there you can use that filter function to check if the value matches your condition.

```js
Object.entries(yourObject).filter(item => item[1] != null)
```

Note: I don't think that checking only for `!= null` will be enough based on the sample you gave.