# Populating form with data from API | React

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, dynamic-forms

I'm getting data for a Vacation object from mySQL server with axios.
I console log the response.data and I see the object as needed.
for some reason, I cant populate the form inputs with the data I get.

```
 const [editedVacation, setEditedVacation] = useState<Vacation>(
    {} as Vacation
  );
 useEffect(() => {
    const getVacation = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<Vacation>(
          `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/vacations/list/${id}`
        );
        setEditedVacation(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getVacation();
  }, [id]);
```

This is the form itself (please note in here I posted the 'destination' part of the form, because its a really long one.)
Also, I'm rendering the form only of editedVacation isn't null / undefined, to make sure the data is there.

```
    {editedVacation && (
          <form className="editVacationForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Typography variant="h4">
              Edit Vacation{" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUmbrellaBeach} color="#FFC857" />
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              defaultValue={editedVacation.destination}
              className="destination"
              type="text"
              label="Destination"
              {...register("destination")}
              error={!!errors.destination}
              helperText={errors.destination?.message}
              onBlur={() => trigger("destination")}
            />
       
          </form>
        )}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Except you're only checking for "truthy" and you initialized editedVacation to an empty object. Which is true. I think you want to init it to undefined. You can see a very simple example of this by looking at devtools and typing `let r = {}; r && 'hi'` vs `let x = undefined; x && 'hi'`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

Two issues. Firstly you say:

> Also, I'm rendering the form only of editedVacation isn't null / undefined, to make sure the data is there.

This is not true since your default value is `{}` which is truthy, so your `editedVacation && (` check will pass even before the data is returned.

Secondly, you are using `defaultValue` but should be using `value`. The former is for uncontrolled inputs, you want controlled here since the state is managed in this parent component.

```
 const [editedVacation, setEditedVacation] = useState<Vacation | null>(
    null
  );
 useEffect(() => {
    const getVacation = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<Vacation>(
          `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/vacations/list/${id}`
        );
        setEditedVacation(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getVacation();
  }, [id]);
```

```
    {editedVacation && (
          <form className="editVacationForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Typography variant="h4">
              Edit Vacation{" "}
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUmbrellaBeach} color="#FFC857" />
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              value={editedVacation.destination}
              className="destination"
              type="text"
              label="Destination"
              {...register("destination")}
              error={!!errors.destination}
              helperText={errors.destination?.message}
              onBlur={() => trigger("destination")}
            />
       
          </form>
        )}
```

Comment: @asdy
I'm afraid this doesn't work as well, although I do realize that when I pass ({}) as the initial state results in a truthy value rather than null.
I've tried changing to null to begin with, but still the data won't populate the inputs.. /:

Comment: I found the issue, its quite stupid.
my backend returns an array of objects (in this case just one object).
once I say setEditedVacation(response.data[0]) - it works.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Cool! Make sure you still apply the above fixes too :)