# How do you check that a number is NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, nan

I’ve only been trying it in Firefox’s JavaScript console, but neither of the following statements return true:

```
parseFloat('geoff') == NaN;

parseFloat('geoff') == Number.NaN;
```

Comment: worth reading if your actual goal is to check numbers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-testing-for-nan-in-javascript.html

Comment: @Gothdo: sure, but I did ask how to check that a *number* is NaN, as opposed to any value.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, but lots of people come here when Googling something like "how to check if a variable is nan in javascript".

Comment: PaulD.Waite I agree with you, but I have the same concern as @Gothdo has. Many people land on this question with the intention as "How to check if a value in JS is NaN".

You can check mjohnsonengr's comment on [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32137779/893612).

BTW, I too have flagged [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript) for moderators attention.

Comment: @dopeddude: yeah I suggested this question should be closed as a duplicate of 30314447 when I flagged it. That might help.

Comment: @Gothdo: those people need to learn to read things carefully.

Comment: NaN is not equal to NaN for some reason
Check with `NaN == NaN` and it returns false
The thing is, there is nothing you can compare with NaN which will make it say it's equal

Comment: in ES6 (aka ECMAScript 2015), use Number.isNaN, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript/32013663#32013663) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Answer (score 732, accepted):

Try this code:

```
isNaN(parseFloat("geoff"))
```

For checking whether *any* value is NaN, instead of just numbers, see here: [How do you test for NaN in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30314447/how-do-you-test-for-nan-in-javascript)

Comment: Is there a need for paseFloat?

Comment: If you want an empty string to be interpreted as `NaN`, then yes. (I’m not saying you always would.)

Comment: If i were you i would  assign it to a variable and , use condition variable !==  variable . As it is laid out in specs https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isnan-number

Comment: `isNaN(parseFloat("geoff")) // true`
`isNaN(parseFloat("10geo")) // false`


How's this useful?

Comment: This could also be useful as to try out https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Comment: @PaulD.Waite and why it should be `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: parseInt(".3") is NaN but parseFloat(".3") is a number.

Answer (score 179):

I just came across this technique in the book [Effective JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321812182) that is pretty simple:

*Since NaN is the only JavaScript value that is treated as unequal to itself, you can always test if a value is NaN by checking it for equality to itself:*

```
var a = NaN;
a !== a; // true 

var b = "foo";
b !== b; // false 

var c = undefined; 
c !== c; // false

var d = {};
d !== d; // false

var e = { valueOf: "foo" }; 
e !== e; // false
```

Didn't realize this until @allsyed commented, but this is in the ECMA spec: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-isnan-number

Comment: Sure: also noted in [@MrAzulay’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220688/20578).

Comment: Effective but counterintuitive. I wouldn't want to maintain this kind of code.

Comment: It's not the code that's counterintuitive, it's NaN.

Comment: This is a bad idea. What if some new object introduced in some future version of JavaScript also doesn't equal itself? Or if NaN is improved in the future and this bug goes away?

Comment: @DanM It's not a bug, it's the standard IEE754 behavior of NaN. It's how it's implemented in CPUs, and it's the expected behavior in every programming language in the world that uses floats.

Comment: @Tarmil Duly noted! That's actually really interesting; I always thought NaN inequality weirdness was a Javascript thing.

Comment: Must it be done with the strict equality operator `!==` or can it be done with the regular `!=`?

Comment: Best to always use === and !==

Comment: A bit weird looking at it. Would you suggest using a function to abstract it? Or would NaN do something bad there too?

Comment: @BlackPanther There **already is a function**: `isNaN`. And NaN is not doing "something bad" here or elsewhere.

Comment: NaN === Nan;  // false. This is a known bug in javascript. isNan is a new method.

Comment: @atilkan - It's not a bug, it's a feature.`NaN` isn't a value, it's a signal that something went wrong. Moreover, it's a signal that mathematic operations, including `===`, won't produce sane results. `+"foo" === +undefined` shouldn't evaluate to `true`, and `+"foo" === +"bar"` would be arguably worse.

Comment: `Since NaN is the only JavaScript value that is treated as unequal to itself` - excellent @Jazzy

Answer (score 64):

Use this code:

```
isNaN('geoff');
```

See [`isNaN()` docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```
alert ( isNaN('abcd'));  // alerts true
alert ( isNaN('2.0'));  // alerts false
alert ( isNaN(2.0));  // alerts false
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but the idea of NaN gets confusing when ```var value = 0/0;``` and ```var value2= String("123 131");``` create NaN values and something like this ```var value3 = "abcd";``` is also a NaN value.

Comment: @NickPineda Why?

Answer (score 52):

As far as a value of type [Number](http://es5.github.io/#x8.5) is to be tested whether it is a `NaN` or not, the global function `isNaN` will do the work

```
isNaN(any-Number);
```

---

For a generic approach which works for all the types in JS, we can use any of the following:

For ECMAScript-5 Users:

```
#1
if(x !== x) {
    console.info('x is NaN.');
}
else {
    console.info('x is NOT a NaN.');
}
```

For people using ECMAScript-6:

```
#2
Number.isNaN(x);
```

And For consistency purpose across ECMAScript 5 & 6 both, we can also use this [polyfill for Number.isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Polyfill)

```
#3
//Polyfill from MDN
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && isNaN(value);
}
// Or
Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(value) {     
    return value !== value;
}
```

please check [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912757/893612) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for not just using "isNan()" but rather providing a completely detailed answer.  This is EXACTLY what I was looking for when I found this question on Google.

Comment: *".... was giving wrong results for the above cases"* I wouldn't say wrong, just different, because the global `isNaN` converts the argument to a number value first.

Comment: @FelixKling Please check the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: isNaN("lorem ipsum"); //true with ES5 was blowing my mind

Comment: @NickPineda The feeling is so mutual, but finally MDN could explain it this way "When the argument to the isNaN function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is NaN."

Comment: Basic difference is that one checks for "not a number" other one checks if it's not the special `NaN`, `Number.isNaN("aa")` therefore returns `false` and `isNaN("aa")` returns `true`.

Answer (score 20):

You should use the global `isNaN(value)` function call, because:

- It is supported cross-browser
- See [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp) for documentation

Examples:

```
 isNaN('geoff'); // true
 isNaN('3'); // false
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah, `isNaN('') //false` but `parseInt('') //NaN`. The same can be said for `null`.

Answer (score 19):

As of **ES6**, `Object.is(..)` is a new utility that can be used to test two values for absolute equality:

```
var a = 3 / 'bar';
Object.is(a, NaN); // true
```

Comment: [NaN doc at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Comment: The two keetss below are different.
var a = 0/0;
console.log(a === NaN); // false
console.log(Object.is(a, NaN)); // true

Answer (score 17):

NaN is a special value that can't be tested like that. An interesting thing I just wanted to share is this

```
var nanValue = NaN;
if(nanValue !== nanValue) // Returns true!
    alert('nanValue is NaN');
```

This returns true **only** for NaN values and Is a safe way of testing. Should definitely be wrapped in a function or atleast commented, because It doesnt make much sense obviously to test if the same variable is not equal to each other, hehe.

Comment: That's not a perfectly reliable way. As per the specs. variable !== variable is most reliable way to check for NaN

Comment: See my answer above on this ^

Answer (score 14):

NaN in JavaScript stands for "Not A Number", although its type is actually number.

```
typeof(NaN) // "number"
```

To check if a variable is of value NaN, we cannot simply use function isNaN(), because isNaN() has the following issue, see below:

```
var myVar = "A";
isNaN(myVar) // true, although "A" is not really of value NaN
```

What really happens here is that myVar is implicitly coerced to a number:

```
var myVar = "A";
isNaN(Number(myVar)) // true. Number(myVar) is NaN here in fact
```

It actually makes sense, because "A" is actually not a number. But what we really want to check is if myVar is exactly of value NaN.

So isNaN() cannot help. Then what should we do instead?

In the light that NaN is the only JavaScript value that is treated unequal to itself, so we can check for its equality to itself using !==

```
var myVar; // undefined
myVar !== myVar // false

var myVar = "A";
myVar !== myVar // false

var myVar = NaN
myVar !== myVar // true
```

**So to conclude**, if it is true that a variable !== itself, then this variable is exactly of value NaN:

```
function isOfValueNaN(v) {
    return v !== v;
}

var myVar = "A";
isNaN(myVar); // true
isOfValueNaN(myVar); // false
```

Answer (score 10):

To fix the issue where `'1.2geoff'` becomes parsed, just use the `Number()` parser instead.

So rather than this:

```
parseFloat('1.2geoff'); // => 1.2
isNaN(parseFloat('1.2geoff')); // => false
isNaN(parseFloat('.2geoff')); // => false
isNaN(parseFloat('geoff')); // => true
```

Do this:

```
Number('1.2geoff'); // => NaN
isNaN(Number('1.2geoff')); // => true
isNaN(Number('.2geoff')); // => true
isNaN(Number('geoff')); // => true
```

EDIT: I just noticed another issue from this though... false values (and true as a real boolean) passed into `Number()` return as `0`! In which case... parseFloat works every time instead. So fall back to that:

```
function definitelyNaN (val) {
    return isNaN(val && val !== true ? Number(val) : parseFloat(val));
}
```

And that covers seemingly everything. I benchmarked it at 90% slower than lodash's `_.isNaN` but then that one doesn't cover all the NaN's:

http://jsperf.com/own-isnan-vs-underscore-lodash-isnan

Just to be clear, mine takes care of the human literal interpretation of something that is "Not a Number" and lodash's takes care of the computer literal interpretation of checking if something is "NaN".

Answer (score 9):

The rule is:

```
NaN != NaN
```

The problem of isNaN() function is that it may return unexpected result in some cases:

```
isNaN('Hello')      //true
isNaN('2005/12/12') //true
isNaN(undefined)    //true
isNaN('NaN')        //true
isNaN(NaN)          //true
isNaN(0 / 0)        //true
```

A better way to check if the value is really NaN is:

```
function is_nan(value) {
    return value != value
}

is_nan(parseFloat("geoff"))
```

Answer (score 8):

While @chiborg 's answer IS correct, there is more to it that should be noted:

```
parseFloat('1.2geoff'); // => 1.2
isNaN(parseFloat('1.2geoff')); // => false
isNaN(parseFloat('.2geoff')); // => false
isNaN(parseFloat('geoff')); // => true
```

Point being, if you're using this method for validation of input, the result will be rather liberal.

So, yes you can use `parseFloat(string)` (or in the case of full numbers `parseInt(string, radix)`' and then subsequently wrap that with `isNaN()`, but be aware of the gotcha with numbers intertwined with additional non-numeric characters.

Comment: Interesting.  Any way to counter this and detect that "1.2geoff" is not really a valid number string?

Comment: Note that this happens only when the string **begins** with a number. `parseFloat('test1.2')` will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 6):

## Simple Solution!

REALLY super simple! Here! Have this method!

```
function isReallyNaN(a) { return a !== a; };
```

Use as simple as:

```
if (!isReallyNaN(value)) { return doingStuff; }
```

> [See performance test <kbd>here</kbd>](https://jsperf.com/isnan-method-test/) using this func vs [<kbd>selected answer</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652319/how-do-you-check-that-a-number-is-nan-in-javascript/#answer-2652335)
>
> Also: See below 1st example for a couple alternate implementations.

---

### Example:

```js
function isReallyNaN(a) { return a !== a; };

var example = {
    'NaN': NaN,
    'an empty Objet': {},
    'a parse to NaN': parseFloat('$5.32'),
    'a non-empty Objet': { a: 1, b: 2 },
    'an empty Array': [],
    'a semi-passed parse': parseInt('5a5'),
    'a non-empty Array': [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    'Math to NaN': Math.log(-1),
    'an undefined object': undefined
  }

for (x in example) {
    var answer = isReallyNaN(example[x]),
        strAnswer = answer.toString();
    $("table").append($("<tr />", { "class": strAnswer }).append($("<th />", {
        html: x
    }), $("<td />", {
        html: strAnswer
    })))
};
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: 2px 5px; }
.true { color: red; }
.false { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

There are a couple alternate paths you take for implementaion, if you don't want to use an alternately named method, and would like to ensure it's more globally available. ***Warning*** These solutions involve altering native objects, and may not be your best solution. Always use caution and be aware that other Libraries you might use may depend on native code or similar alterations.

#### Alternate Implementation 1: Replace Native `isNaN` method.

```
//  Extremely simple. Just simply write the method.
window.isNaN = function(a) { return a !==a; }
```

#### Alternate Implementation 2: Append to Number Object
<sup>*Suggested as it is also a poly-fill for ECMA 5 to 6</sup>

```
Number['isNaN'] || (Number.isNaN = function(a) { return a !== a });
//  Use as simple as
Number.isNaN(NaN)
```

---

*Alternate solution <sub>test if empty</sub>*

A simple window method I wrote that test if object is ***Empty***. It's a little different in that it doesn't give if item is *"exactly" NaN*, but I figured I'd throw this up as it may also be useful when looking for empty items.

```
/** isEmpty(varried)
 *  Simple method for testing if item is "empty"
 **/
;(function() {
   function isEmpty(a) { return (!a || 0 >= a) || ("object" == typeof a && /\{\}|\[(null(,)*)*\]/.test(JSON.stringify(a))); };
   window.hasOwnProperty("empty")||(window.empty=isEmpty);
})();
```

### Example:

```js
;(function() {
   function isEmpty(a) { return !a || void 0 === a || a !== a || 0 >= a || "object" == typeof a && /\{\}|\[(null(,)*)*\]/.test(JSON.stringify(a)); };
   window.hasOwnProperty("empty")||(window.empty=isEmpty);
})();

var example = {
    'NaN': NaN,
    'an empty Objet': {},
    'a parse to NaN': parseFloat('$5.32'),
    'a non-empty Objet': { a: 1, b: 2 },
    'an empty Array': new Array(),
    'an empty Array w/ 9 len': new Array(9),
    'a semi-passed parse': parseInt('5a5'),
    'a non-empty Array': [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    'Math to NaN': Math.log(-1),
    'an undefined object': undefined
  }

for (x in example) {
 var answer = empty(example[x]),
  strAnswer = answer.toString();
 $("#t1").append(
  $("<tr />", { "class": strAnswer }).append(
   $("<th />", { html: x }),
   $("<td />", { html: strAnswer.toUpperCase() })
  )
 )
};


function isReallyNaN(a) { return a !== a; };
for(x in example){var answer=isReallyNaN(example[x]),strAnswer=answer.toString();$("#t2").append($("<tr />",{"class":strAnswer}).append($("<th />",{html:x}),$("<td />",{html:strAnswer.toUpperCase()})))};
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; float: left; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: 2px 5px; }
.true { color: red; }
.false { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">isEmpty()</th></tr></thead><thead><tr><th>Value Type</th><th>Bool Return</th></tr></thead></table>
<table id="t2"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">isReallyNaN()</th></tr></thead><thead><tr><th>Value Type</th><th>Bool Return</th></tr></thead></table>
```

---

#### Extremely Deep Check If Is Empty

This last one goes a bit deep, even checking if an Object is full of blank Objects. I'm sure it has room for improvement and possible pits, but so far, it appears to catch most everything.

```js
function isEmpty(a) {
 if (!a || 0 >= a) return !0;
 if ("object" == typeof a) {
  var b = JSON.stringify(a).replace(/"[^"]*":(0|"0*"|false|null|\{\}|\[(null(,)?)*\]),?/g, '').replace(/"[^"]*":\{\},?/g, '');
  if ( /^$|\{\}|\[\]/.test(b) ) return !0;
  else if (a instanceof Array)  {
   b = b.replace(/(0|"0*"|false|null|\{\}|\[(null(,)?)*\]),?/g, '');
   if ( /^$|\{\}|\[\]/.test(b) ) return !0;
  }
 }
 return false;
}
window.hasOwnProperty("empty")||(window.empty=isEmpty);

var example = {
    'NaN': NaN,
    'an empty Objet': {},
    'a parse to NaN': parseFloat('$5.32'),
    'a non-empty Objet': { a: 1, b: 2 },
    'an empty Array': new Array(),
    'an empty Array w/ 9 len': new Array(9),
    'a semi-passed parse': parseInt('5a5'),
    'a non-empty Array': [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    'Math to NaN': Math.log(-1),
    'an undefined object': undefined,
    'Object Full of Empty Items': { 1: '', 2: [], 3: {}, 4: false, 5:new Array(3), 6: NaN, 7: null, 8: void 0, 9: 0, 10: '0', 11: { 6: NaN, 7: null, 8: void 0 } },
    'Array Full of Empty Items': ["",[],{},false,[null,null,null],null,null,null,0,"0",{"6":null,"7":null}]
  }

for (x in example) {
 var answer = empty(example[x]),
  strAnswer = answer.toString();
 $("#t1").append(
  $("<tr />", { "class": strAnswer }).append(
   $("<th />", { html: x }),
   $("<td />", { html: strAnswer.toUpperCase() })
  )
 )
};


function isReallyNaN(a) { return a !== a; };
for(x in example){var answer=isReallyNaN(example[x]),strAnswer=answer.toString();$("#t2").append($("<tr />",{"class":strAnswer}).append($("<th />",{html:x}),$("<td />",{html:strAnswer.toUpperCase()})))};
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; float: left; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: 2px 5px; }
.true { color: red; }
.false { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">isEmpty()</th></tr></thead><thead><tr><th>Value Type</th><th>Bool Return</th></tr></thead></table>
<table id="t2"><thead><tr><th colspan="2">isReallyNaN()</th></tr></thead><thead><tr><th>Value Type</th><th>Bool Return</th></tr></thead></table>
```

Comment: @PaulD.Waite maybe its this app, but I dont see an accepted answer. In fact, I only see about 5 answers, but I see it says there are 15

Comment: What app are you using?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The SE one for android. on galaxy s3

Comment: Aha. I don’t have the app to look myself, but here’s a link to the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2652335/20578

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ah, I see. I suppose, in direct answer to only the question in and of itself, that answer may suffice. I posted my answer on another question in total relation to "JS way to check if is 'really' NaN", since `isNaN` is NOT reliable. I was commented there and told this question would better suit my answer, thus moving it here. Simply just putting something helpful/useful out there in relation to this issue that will pop up on a Google search of the issue at hand, `is it NaN?`. On side note, my answer would be more acurate more often than selected answer.

Answer (score 6):

**If your environment supports ECMAScript 2015**, then you might want to use [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) to make sure that the value is really `NaN`.

The problem with [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) is, [if you use that with non-numeric data there are few confusing rules (as per MDN) are applied.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior) For example,

```
isNaN(NaN);       // true
isNaN(undefined); // true
isNaN({});        // true
```

So, in ECMA Script 2015 supported environments, you might want to use

```
Number.isNaN(parseFloat('geoff'))
```

Comment: My environment only supports ECMAScript XP Home Edition :(

Comment: @PaulD.Waite (I hope you meant IE 6 :D) No problem :-) Just remember that `isNaN` could get you in trouble and remember to use `Number.isNaN` in ECMAScript 2015 environments :-)

Answer (score 6):

```js
function isNotANumber(n) {
  if (typeof n !== 'number') {
    return true;
  } 
  return n !== n;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 5):

I use [underscore's `isNaN`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isNaN) function because in JavaScript:

```
isNaN(undefined) 
-> true
```

At the least, be aware of that gotcha.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would isNaN returning true when passed `undefined` be incorrect behavior? It IS true that `undefined` is not a number, is it not?

Comment: @Xaxis NaN should not be considered equivalent to undefined, they are both special values with specific and *different* meanings. Consider this: I have a value but I'm not telling what it is, maybe it is a number and maybe it isn't, nevertheless, from your point of view, it's undefined.

Comment: @Corin `undefined` may be something different than `NaN`, however it is still not a number so `isNaN(undefined)` should be (and is) `true`

Answer (score 5):

I just want to share another alternative, it's not necessarily better than others here, but I think it's worth looking at:

```
function customIsNaN(x) { return (typeof x == 'number' && x != 0 && !x); }
```

The logic behind this is that every number except `0` and `NaN` are cast to `true`.

I've done a quick test, and it performs as good as `Number.isNaN` and as checking against itself for false. All three perform better than `isNan`

The results

```
customIsNaN(NaN);            // true
customIsNaN(0/0);            // true
customIsNaN(+new Date('?')); // true

customIsNaN(0);          // false
customIsNaN(false);      // false
customIsNaN(null);       // false
customIsNaN(undefined);  // false
customIsNaN({});         // false
customIsNaN('');         // false
```

May become useful if you want to avoid the broken `isNaN` function.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe also this:

```
function isNaNCustom(value){
    return value.toString() === 'NaN' && 
           typeof value !== 'string' && 
           typeof value === 'number'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that isNaN() is not supported in Node.js out of the box.
I worked around with

```
var value = 1;
if (parseFloat(stringValue)+"" !== "NaN") value = parseFloat(stringValue);
```

Comment: Sure, but I wasn't asking about Node.js.

Answer (score 3):

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```

> Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against NaN.

Look at [Mozilla Documentation **The global NaN property is a value representing Not-A-Numbe**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

The best way is using 'isNaN()' which is buit-in function  to check NaN. All browsers supports the way..

Answer (score 2):

According to IEEE 754, all relationships involving NaN evaluate as false except !=.  Thus, for example, (A >= B) = false and (A <= B) = false if A or B or both is/are NaN.

Answer (score 2):

*I wrote this answer to another question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992553/nan-replacement-in-node-js-with-an-integer) where another checks when `NaN == null` but then it was marked as duplicate so I don't want to waste my job.*

Look at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) about `NaN`.

---

#### Short answer

Just use `distance || 0` when you want to be sure you value is a proper number or `isNaN()` to check it.

#### Long answer

The NaN (Not-a-Number) is a weirdo Global Object in javascript frequently returned when some mathematical operation failed.

You wanted to check if `NaN == null` which results `false`. Hovewer even `NaN == NaN` results with `false`.

A Simple way to find out if variable is `NaN` is an global function `isNaN()`.

Another is `x !== x` which is only true when x is NaN. (thanks for remind to @raphael-schweikert)

#### But why the short answer worked?

Let's find out.

When you call `NaN == false` the result is `false`, same with `NaN == true`.

Somewhere in specifications JavaScript has an record with always false values, which includes:

- `NaN` - Not-a-Number
- `""` - empty string
- `false` - a boolean false
- `null` - null object
- `undefined` - undefined variables
- `0` - numerical 0, including +0 and -0

Comment: “Only simple way to find out if variable is NaN is an global function isNaN()” – not true; there is another simple way: `var xIsNaN = x !== x;` This yields true only if x is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is mentioned in [MDN's parseFloat page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

It provides a filter function to do strict parsing

```
var filterFloat = function (value) {
    if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/
      .test(value))
      return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}


console.log(filterFloat('421'));               // 421
console.log(filterFloat('-421'));              // -421
console.log(filterFloat('+421'));              // 421
console.log(filterFloat('Infinity'));          // Infinity
console.log(filterFloat('1.61803398875'));     // 1.61803398875
console.log(filterFloat('421e+0'));            // NaN
console.log(filterFloat('421hop'));            // NaN
console.log(filterFloat('hop1.61803398875'));  // NaN
```

And then you can use `isNaN` to check if it is `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

Found another way, just for fun.

```
function IsActuallyNaN(obj) {
  return [obj].includes(NaN);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact way to check is:

```
//takes care of boolen, undefined and empty

isNaN(x) || typeof(x) ==='boolean' || typeof(x) !=='undefined' || x!=='' ? 'is really a nan' : 'is a number'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this little function that works like a charm.
Instead of checking for NaN which seems to be counter intuitive, you check for a number. I'm pretty sure I am not the first to do it this way, but I thought i'd share.

```
function isNum(val){
    var absVal = Math.abs(val);
    var retval = false;
    if((absVal-absVal) == 0){
        retval = true
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

marksyzm's answer works well, but it does not return false for `Infinity` as Infinity is techinicly not a number.

i came up with a `isNumber` function that will check if it is a number.

```js
function isNumber(i) {
    return !isNaN(i && i !== true ? Number(i) : parseFloat(i)) && [Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY].indexOf(i) === -1;
}

console.log(isNumber(Infinity));
console.log(isNumber("asdf"));
console.log(isNumber(1.4));
console.log(isNumber(NaN));
console.log(isNumber(Number.MAX_VALUE));
console.log(isNumber("1.68"));
```

UPDATE:
i noticed that this code fails for some parameters, so i made it better.

```js
function isNumber(i) {//function for checking if parameter is number
if(!arguments.length) {
throw new SyntaxError("not enough arguments.");
 } else if(arguments.length > 1) {
throw new SyntaxError("too many arguments.");
 } else if([Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY].indexOf(i) !== -1) {
throw new RangeError("number cannot be \xB1infinity.");
 } else if(typeof i === "object" && !(i instanceof RegExp) && !(i instanceof Number) && !(i === null)) {
throw new TypeError("parameter cannot be object/array.");
 } else if(i instanceof RegExp) {
throw new TypeError("parameter cannot be RegExp.");
 } else if(i == null || i === undefined) {
throw new ReferenceError("parameter is null or undefined.");
 } else {
return !isNaN(i && i !== true ? Number(i) : parseFloat(i)) && (i === i);
 }
}
console.log(isNumber(Infinity));
console.log(isNumber(this));
console.log(isNumber(/./ig));
console.log(isNumber(null));
```

Comment: Your premise the infinity is technically not a number is technically flawed : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number . From my reading of the answers is that infinity being a number depends on context.

Comment: i'm going to move this to another question

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("1234567890.".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(mycharacter))>-1);
```

This is not elegant. but after trying isNAN() I arrived at this solution which is another alternative. In this example I also allowed '.' because I am masking for float. You could also reverse this to make sure no numbers are used.

```
("1234567890".indexOf(String.fromCharCode(mycharacter))==-1)
```

This is a single character evaluation but you could also loop through a string to check for any numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Number('hello').toString() === 'NaN' // true
Number(undefined).toString() === 'NaN' // true
    
Number('12345').toString() === 'NaN' // false  

// These all evaluate to 0 which is a number
Number('').toString() === 'NaN' // false // 0
Number('0').toString() === 'NaN' // false // 0
Number().toString() === 'NaN' // false // 0

// These all evaluate to 0 and 1 which is a number
Number(false).toString() === 'NaN' // false // 0
Number(true).toString() === 'NaN' // false // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try both in condition

```
if(isNaN(parseFloat('geoff'))  && typeof(parseFloat('geoff')) === "number");
//true
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be useful

```
    // Long-hand const isFalsey = (value) => {   if (
        value === null ||
        value === undefined ||
        value === 0 ||
        value === false ||
        value === NaN ||
        value === ""   ) {
        return true;   }   return false; };
 // Short-hand const 
      isFalsey = (value) => !value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply convert the result to String and compare with 'NaN'.

```
var val = Number("test");
if(String(val) === 'NaN') {
   console.log("true");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is **(NaN >= 0)** ?...... "**I don't Know**".

```
function IsNotNumber( i ){
    if( i >= 0 ){ return false; }
    if( i <= 0 ){ return false; }
    return true;
}
```

Conditions only execute if **TRUE**.

Not on **FALSE**.

Not on "**I Don't Know**".

Comment: not very useful if you explicitly look for NaN values istead of looking for the opposite

Answer (score -2):

So I see several responses to this,

But I just use:

```
function isNaN(x){
     return x == x && typeof x == 'number';
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `return x != x && typeof x === 'number'` ?